# SVG drop shadow using css3

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

Is it possible to set drop shadow for an svg element using css3, something like

```
box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px #888;
```

I saw some remarks on creating shadow using filter effects. Is there an example of using CSS alone. Below is a working code where the cursor style is correctly applied, but no shadow effect. How can I get the shadow effect with the least bit of code?

```css
svg .shadow { 
  cursor:crosshair; 
  -moz-box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px #888;
  box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px #888; 
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full"  viewBox="0 0 120 70">  
    <rect class="shadow" x="10" y="10" width="100" height="50" fill="#c66" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 412, accepted):

Here's an [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/arrow-with-dropshadow.svg) of applying dropshadow to some svg using the 'filter' property. If you want to control the opacity of the dropshadow have a look at [this example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/arrow-with-dropshadow-lighter.svg). The `slope` attribute controls how much opacity to give to the dropshadow.

Relevant bits from the example:

```
<filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> <!-- stdDeviation is how much to blur -->
  <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> <!-- how much to offset -->
  <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.5"/> <!-- slope is the opacity of the shadow -->
  </feComponentTransfer>
  <feMerge> 
    <feMergeNode/> <!-- this contains the offset blurred image -->
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> <!-- this contains the element that the filter is applied to -->
  </feMerge>
</filter>
<circle r="10" style="filter:url(#dropshadow)"/>
```

Box-shadow is defined to work on CSS boxes (read: rectangles), while svg is a bit more expressive than just rectangles. Read the [SVG Primer](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#filters) to learn a bit more about what you can do with SVG filters.

Comment: Is there a way of controlling the opacity of the dropshadow?

Comment: @HughGuiney: yes, of course. Here's an example of one way of doing that, http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/arrow-with-dropshadow-lighter.svg. Just vary the `slope` attribute to tweak how much opacity you want.

Comment: Note that Internet Explorer and Safari do not support SVG filters yet: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_feoffset.asp

Comment: @LorenzoPolidori IE10 and Safari 5.2 both support SVG filters.

Comment: Fair enough, though I still have Safari 5.1 on my Mac and the Safari version on my iPad2 with the latest iOS 5.1.1 does not support it either. If you need it for earlier versions of Safari, a good alternative is the style attribute `-webkit-svg-shadow`.

Comment: Note that there is no XML node nesting apart from feMergeNode being inside feMerge.  The indentation in the code is a bit misleading - I thought feOffset and feMerge were child nodes of feGaussianBlr.

Comment: This filter appears to render vertical lines invisible.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth post a new question please, but in general I think that just happens because of the zero bbox width for a straight vertical line (and the filter is relative to the bbox in the example here). See last paragraph of http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ObjectBoundingBoxUnits.

Comment: I can figure a workaround; I just was informing you (and others) of my observation. It even occurs when the stroke width is, say, 3.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth right, stroke doesn't affect the default (filled) boundingbox. We're extending this in SVG2, but you'd still probably need to opt in for it to be computed relative to e.g the stroked boundingbox.

Comment: Example on how to implement this approach in D3.js: http://bl.ocks.org/cpbotha/5200394

Comment: PLEASE Anyone can help me , please add shadow for this svg http://jsfiddle.net/8fx3p4zo/  @ErikDahlström   Its very urgent for me  I tried lot but i couldn't solution

Comment: @ShibinRagh this particular solution is for putting the filter inside the svg, if you want to apply this from outside see e.g the answer below, here's one way of doing it: http://jsfiddle.net/ym35zed1/.

Comment: @ErikDahlström Really thanks its working , but I don't know how it work on mozilla ? "-moz-filter"  its not working for me

Comment: Thanks but my mozilla not supporting , version is 34.0.5 @ErikDahlström

Comment: @ShibinRagh please post a new (and more specific) question re firefox support instead (or file a moz bugreport), this comment thread is already way too long.

Comment: How do you add color to the shadow?

Comment: @Costa see e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965196/svg-color-of-the-shadow

Answer (score 806):

Use the CSS [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#drop-shadow()_2) property.

[Supported by webkit browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters), Firefox 34+ and Edge.

You can use this [polyfill](https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill) that will support FF < 34, IE6+.

You would use it like so:

```css
/* Use -webkit- only if supporting: Chrome < 54, iOS < 9.3, Android < 4.4.4 */

.shadow {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
  filter: drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
  /* Similar syntax to box-shadow */
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Star_wars2.svg" alt="" class="shadow" width="200">

<!-- Or -->

<svg class="shadow" ...>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="200" height="100" fill="#bada55" />
</svg>

<!-- Or -->

<svg>
  <g fill="none" stroke="#decade" stroke-width="2" transform="scale(2)">
    <circle class="shadow" cx="20" cy="20" r="19"/>
    <path class="shadow" d="M 20,1 V 39"/>
    <path class="shadow" d="M 20,1 V 20" transform="rotate(135, 20, 20)"/>
    <path class="shadow" d="M 20,1 V 20" transform="rotate(225, 20, 20)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

This approach differs from the css `box-shadow` effect in that it accounts for opacity and does not apply the drop shadow effect to the box but rather to the outline of the svg element itself.

**NOTE**: This approach used to work when the class was placed on the `<svg>` element alone. **You can now use this on an inline svg element such as `<rect>`.**

Read more about css filters [here](https://web.dev/learn/css/filters/).

Comment: This appears to work for images, or for the whole svg, but for selections inside the svg. [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MhhAx/1/)

Comment: Using  filter: drop-shadow() or box-shadow in webkit is the same for svg element. Still no solution for inner elements.

Comment: @heneryville Not sure what you mean by that comment? See example here: http://jsbin.com/dipusemiye

Comment: @hitautodestruct in your example the filter is applied to the whole image, what @aesede is trying to do is applying it to an element *inside* an SVG, like a `g` or a `path`.

Comment: Open up your `svg` file and add a class to your `g` or `path` element.

Comment: Perfect, work with `<img>` and `background-image` :)

Comment: Perfect answer. And it's support by almost all browsers except the ever stupid IE9-

Checkout here for more http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20filters
Also take a look at the resources tab for some cool examples.

Comment: This doesn't work for applying drop-shadows to svg elements in any way. **do not use it.** Example of failure: http://jsbin.com/bepurahuwa/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @AndyRay works like a charm... http://jsbin.com/peviso/edit?html,css,js,output. You put the class on the <svg> tag.

Comment: @hitautodestruct yes, it does work like that. The **real** problem comes when you need too apply filter to an element, but not to others.

Comment: I guess both @AndyRay and hitautodestruct are right, because as [pointed out here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460182/how-to-apply-drop-shadow-filter-via-css-to-svg-specific-element-path), this looks like a Chrome rendering issue: Firefox is rendering correctly the filter on SVG specific elements.

Comment: Does NOT work with current Chrome version ( 54.0.2840). If you use images (as stated in other comments) it works, but not for a <rect> or <circle>.

Comment: @Pianoman I'm using Chrome (54.0.2840.98) OSx. Just made a [quick test](http://jsbin.com/gejopo/edit?html,css,output) with `<rect>` and it seems to work

Comment: @hitautodestruct I tried using this jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ddonsv5f/1/). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Pianoman You put the class directly on the `<rect class="shadow">` element. The class should be on the svg `<svg class="shadow">`.

Comment: @hitautodestruct ah! that explains it. Not an option for me, as I do not want everything to have a shadow. But thank you for your support.

Comment: Correct. Only works for the whole svg element. The svg should also not have a background color. if it does, the shadow will become just a rectangle.

Comment: The answer states that the `-webkit-filter` setting is only needed for iOS < 9.3, but I found I needed to use it for my Cordova app running on 10.3.3. If I just used `filter` my  app would crash after a couple of minutes. Perhaps Cordova uses an older webkit version by default.

Comment: @hitautodestruct, in reality it is not correct that you need to add the class to the SVG tag only; in the following demo I added two different classes to generate different drop-shadows for the "text" and the "path" tags of a svg generated dynamically: https://codepen.io/ChemBioScripting/pen/wEXrjB

Comment: @AndyRay, take a look a this demo (https://codepen.io/ChemBioScripting/pen/wEXrjB): I added different classes to "path" and "text" of a SVG. In the code I commented another alternative way that does not use the classes

Comment: Using css filter drop-shadow seems to set the element to relative and you are unable to change it.

Comment: FYI, the posted code works for me on a Font Awesome icon (in Elementor) which is vector-based (and I'll assume it uses SVG); the shadow follows all the edges of the symbol.

Comment: This is masterful! I succesfully used this on a toolbar that has SVGs only on the side...
The filter followed the entire shape (on the container of course) perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 140):

You can easily add a drop-shadow effect to an svg-element using the drop-shadow() CSS function and rgba color values. By using rgba color values you can change the opacity of your shadow.

```css
img.light-shadow{
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}

img.dark-shadow{
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
}
```

```html
<img class="light-shadow" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg" />
<img class="dark-shadow" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg" />
```

Comment: @Foxhoundn This is definitely the modern solution, and should be accepted as the answer.

Comment: Internet Explorer 11: Fail (no drop shadow but the original SVG image is shown). Firefox (Release & ESR): OK. Google Chrome: OK. Edge Legacy: OK.

Comment: dam, if this only worked on groups and shapes in the SVG!

Answer (score 54):

Easiest way I've found is with `feDropShadow`.

```
<filter id="shadow" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
  <feDropShadow dx="3" dy="3" stdDeviation="1" flood-color="#ff0000" flood-opacity="1" />
</filter>
```

On the element:

```
<path d="..." filter="url(#shadow)"/>
```

Comment: I did some reading and now that I understand your answer you definitely get that upvote. This answer is not appreciated enough. However, a little bit more explanation would bee good. This example for instance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feDropShadow#SVG

Comment: For this to work, you need to add `filter:url(#shadow)` to the element you want to have a shadow (`#shadow` is the id of the `filter` tag). For example `<path d="..." style="filter:url(#shadow)"/>`. Maybe you should add that to your answer.

Comment: Having smaller values in ```feDropShadow dx="40" dy="40" stdDeviation="35"``` , such as 3,3,1 instead on 40,40,35 might save some confusion.

Answer (score 2):

### Black text with white shadow

Another way, I used for white shadow (on text): create a clone for shadow:

**Note**: This require `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` at SVG declaration.

Real text value is located in `<defs>` section, with position and style, but without a `fill` definition.

The text is cloned two times: first for shadow and second for the text itself.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="640" height="70"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
  <filter id="Blur"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.8" /></filter>
  <text style="font-family:sans,helvetica;font-weight:bold;font-size:12pt"
      id="Text"><tspan x="12" y="19">
        Black text with white shadow
    </tspan></text>
  </defs>
  <rect style="fill:#8AB" width="640" height="70" />
  <use style="fill:white;" filter="url(#Blur)" xlink:href="#Text"
      transform="translate(1.8,.9)"/>
  <use style="fill:black;" xlink:href="#Text"/>
</svg>
```

More *distant* shadow with biggest value as *blur deviation*:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="640" height="70"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
  <filter id="Blur"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" /></filter>
  <text style="font-family:sans,helvetica;font-weight:bold;font-size:12pt"
      id="Text"><tspan x="12" y="19">
        Black text with white shadow
    </tspan></text>
  </defs>
  <rect style="fill:#8AB" width="640" height="70" />
  <use style="fill:white;" filter="url(#Blur)" xlink:href="#Text"
      transform="translate(7,5)"/>
  <use style="fill:black;" xlink:href="#Text"/>
</svg>
```

### You can use this same approach with regular SVG objects.

With same requirement: ***No fill definition at `<defs>` section***!

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="364" height="172"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <filter id="Blur"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.8" /></filter>
    <g transform="matrix(.7,0,0,.7,-117.450795,-335.320895)" id="Img">
        <g transform="matrix(12.997776,0,0,-12.997776,389.30313,662.04015)">
            <path d="m 0,0 -1.107,0 c -0.039,0 -0.067,0.044 -0.067,0.086 0,0.015 0.589,1.914 0.589,1.914 0.021,0.071 0.023,0.073 0.031,0.073 l 0.001,0 c 0.009,0 0.01,-0.002 0.031,-0.073 0,0 0.589,-1.899 0.589,-1.914 C 0.067,0.044 0.037,0 0,0 M 1.493,4.345 C 1.482,4.383 1.448,4.411 1.408,4.414 l -4.065,0 C -2.698,4.41 -2.731,4.383 -2.742,4.346 c 0,0 -2.247,-7.418 -2.247,-7.432 0,-0.037 0.029,-0.067 0.067,-0.067 l 2.687,0 c 0.021,0.008 0.037,0.028 0.042,0.051 l 0.313,1 c 0.01,0.025 0.033,0.042 0.061,0.043 l 2.479,0.002 c 0.027,-0.002 0.051,-0.021 0.061,-0.045 l 0.32,-1 c 0.005,-0.023 0.021,-0.044 0.042,-0.052 0,0 2.642,10e-4 2.644,10e-4 0.037,0 0.068,0.028 0.068,0.065 0,0.013 -2.302,7.433 -2.302,7.433" />
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(12.997776,0,0,-12.997776,508.27177,644.93113)">
            <path d="m 0,0 -1.651,-0.001 c 0,0 -0.044,0.013 -0.044,0.063 l -10e-4,0.833 c 0,0.05 0.044,0.063 0.044,0.063 l 1.514,0 C 0.038,0.958 0.394,0.87 0.394,0.463 0.394,0.056 0,0 0,0 m 7.916,0.645 3.741,0 0,2.453 -4.81,0 C 6.397,3.098 5.764,2.866 5.401,2.597 5.038,2.328 4.513,1.715 4.513,0.87 c 0,-0.845 0.513,-1.502 0.513,-1.502 0.263,-0.326 0.925,-1.005 0.925,-1.005 0.015,-0.016 0.024,-0.037 0.024,-0.061 0,-0.051 -0.041,-0.092 -0.092,-0.092 l -3.705,0 c -0.451,0.002 -0.482,0.181 -0.482,0.207 0,0.046 0.056,0.075 0.056,0.075 0.169,0.081 0.514,0.35 0.514,0.35 0.732,0.57 0.82,1.352 0.82,1.771 0,0.42 -0.063,1.163 -0.814,1.814 C 1.521,3.078 0.57,3.096 0.57,3.096 l -5.287,0 c 0,0 0,-7.52 0,-7.522 0,-0.024 0.022,-0.043 0.046,-0.043 l 2.943,0 0,2.11 c 0,0.037 0.057,0 0.057,0 l 1.533,-1.54 c 0.545,-0.551 1.446,-0.57 1.446,-0.57 l 5.796,0.001 c 0.989,0 1.539,0.538 1.69,0.688 0.15,0.151 0.651,0.714 0.651,1.647 0,0.932 -0.426,1.409 -0.608,1.628 C 8.675,-0.309 8.029,0.375 7.894,0.517 7.878,0.53 7.868,0.55 7.868,0.572 c 0,0.033 0.019,0.064 0.048,0.073" />
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(12.997776,0,0,-12.997776,306.99861,703.01559)">
            <path d="m 0,0 c 0.02,0 0.034,0.014 0.04,0.036 0,0 2.277,7.479 2.277,7.486 0,0.02 -0.012,0.042 -0.031,0.044 0,0 -2.805,0 -2.807,0 -0.014,0 -0.023,-0.011 -0.026,-0.026 0,-0.001 -0.581,-1.945 -0.581,-1.946 -0.004,-0.016 -0.012,-0.026 -0.026,-0.026 -0.014,0 -0.026,0.014 -0.028,0.026 L -1.79,7.541 c -0.002,0.013 -0.012,0.025 -0.026,0.025 -10e-4,0 -3.1,0.001 -3.1,0.001 -0.009,-0.002 -0.017,-0.01 -0.02,-0.018 0,0 -0.545,-1.954 -0.545,-1.954 -0.003,-0.017 -0.012,-0.027 -0.027,-0.027 -0.013,0 -0.024,0.01 -0.026,0.023 l -0.578,1.952 c -0.001,0.012 -0.011,0.022 -0.023,0.024 l -2.992,0 c -0.024,0 -0.044,-0.02 -0.044,-0.045 0,-0.004 10e-4,-0.012 10e-4,-0.012 0,0 2.31,-7.471 2.311,-7.474 C -6.853,0.014 -6.839,0 -6.819,0 c 0.003,0 2.485,-0.001 2.485,-0.001 0.015,0.002 0.03,0.019 0.034,0.037 10e-4,0 0.865,2.781 0.865,2.781 0.005,0.017 0.012,0.027 0.026,0.027 0.015,0 0.023,-0.012 0.027,-0.026 L -2.539,0.024 C -2.534,0.01 -2.521,0 -2.505,0 -2.503,0 0,0 0,0" />
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(12.997776,0,0,-12.997776,278.90126,499.03369)">
            <path d="m 0,0 c -0.451,0 -1.083,-0.232 -1.446,-0.501 -0.363,-0.269 -0.888,-0.882 -0.888,-1.727 0,-0.845 0.513,-1.502 0.513,-1.502 0.263,-0.326 0.925,-1.01 0.925,-1.01 0.015,-0.016 0.024,-0.037 0.024,-0.06 0,-0.051 -0.041,-0.093 -0.092,-0.093 -0.008,0 -6.046,0 -6.046,0 l 0,-2.674 7.267,0 c 0.988,0 1.539,0.538 1.69,0.689 0.15,0.15 0.65,0.713 0.65,1.646 0,0.932 -0.425,1.414 -0.607,1.633 -0.162,0.196 -0.808,0.876 -0.943,1.017 -0.016,0.014 -0.026,0.034 -0.026,0.056 0,0.033 0.019,0.063 0.048,0.073 l 3.5,0 0,-5.114 2.691,0 0,5.101 3.267,0 0,2.466 L 0,0 Z" />
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(12.997776,0,0,-12.997776,583.96822,539.30215)">
            <path d="m 0,0 -1.651,-0.001 c 0,0 -0.044,0.013 -0.044,0.063 l -10e-4,0.833 c 0,0.05 0.044,0.063 0.044,0.063 l 1.514,0 C 0.038,0.958 0.394,0.87 0.394,0.463 0.394,0.056 0,0 0,0 m 2.178,-1.79 c -0.45,0.002 -0.482,0.181 -0.482,0.207 0,0.046 0.056,0.075 0.056,0.075 0.169,0.081 0.514,0.35 0.514,0.35 0.732,0.57 0.82,1.352 0.82,1.771 0,0.42 -0.063,1.163 -0.814,1.814 C 1.521,3.078 0.57,3.098 0.57,3.098 l -5.287,0 c 0,0 0,-7.522 0,-7.524 0,-0.024 0.022,-0.043 0.046,-0.043 0.005,0 2.943,0 2.943,0 l 0,2.109 c 0,0.038 0.057,0 0.057,0 l 1.533,-1.539 c 0.545,-0.551 1.446,-0.57 1.446,-0.57 l 4.525,0 0,2.679 -3.655,0 z" />
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(12.997776,0,0,-12.997776,466.86346,556.40203)">
            <path d="m 0,0 -1.107,0 c -0.041,0 -0.067,0.044 -0.067,0.086 0,0.016 0.589,1.914 0.589,1.914 0.021,0.071 0.027,0.073 0.031,0.073 l 0.001,0 c 0.004,0 0.01,-0.002 0.031,-0.073 0,0 0.589,-1.898 0.589,-1.914 C 0.067,0.044 0.04,0 0,0 M 1.49,4.347 C 1.479,4.385 1.446,4.412 1.405,4.414 l -4.065,0 C -2.7,4.412 -2.734,4.385 -2.745,4.348 c 0,0 -2.245,-7.42 -2.245,-7.434 0,-0.037 0.03,-0.067 0.067,-0.067 l 2.687,0 c 0.022,0.007 0.038,0.028 0.043,0.051 l 0.313,1.001 c 0.01,0.024 0.033,0.041 0.061,0.042 l 2.478,0 C 0.687,-2.061 0.71,-2.078 0.721,-2.102 l 0.32,-1 c 0.005,-0.023 0.021,-0.044 0.042,-0.052 0,0 2.642,10e-4 2.644,10e-4 0.037,0 0.067,0.028 0.067,0.066 0,0.012 -2.304,7.434 -2.304,7.434" />
        </g>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <rect style="fill:#8AB" width="364" height="172" />
  <use style="fill:white;" filter="url(#Blur)" xlink:href="#Img"
    transform="translate(1.8,.9)"/>
  <use style="fill:black;" xlink:href="#Img"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to just use `flood-color`?

Comment: *`Blur`* is used to make shadow look a little blurred. See my second text version ***`More distant shadow...`*** (Just added now)

Answer (score 2):

If your SVG element is `<text>`, you can use the CSS property `text-shadow` without any problem. Syntax is `text-shadow: color x-offset-px y-offset-px blur-px`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably an evolution, it appears that inline css filters works nicely on elements, in a certain way.

Declaring a drop-shadow css filter, in an svg element, in both a class or inline does **NOT** works, as specified earlier.

But, at least in **Firefox**, with the following wizardry:

Appending the filter declaration **inline**, with javascript, **after DOM load**.

```js
// Does not works, with regular dynamic css styling:

shadow0.oninput = () => {
  rect1.style.filter = "filter:drop-shadow(0 0 " + shadow0.value + "rem black);"
}

// Okay! Inline styling, appending.

shadow1.oninput = () => {
  rect1.style += " ;filter:drop-shadow(0 0 " + shadow1.value + "rem black);"
  rect2.style += " ;filter:drop-shadow(0 0 " + shadow1.value + "rem black);"
}
```

```html
<h2>Firefox only</h2>
<h4>
Does not works! 
<input id="shadow0" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.1">

 | Okay!
<input id="shadow1" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.1">

<svg viewBox="0 0 120 70">  
    <rect id="rect1" x="10" y="10" width="100" height="50" fill="#c66" />
    
    <!-- Inline style declaration does NOT works at svg level, no shadow at loading: -->
    <rect id="rect2" x="40" y="30" width="10" height="10" fill="#aaa" style="filter:drop-shadow(0 0 20rem black)" />
    
</svg>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of a CSS-only solution.

As you mentioned, filters are the canonical approach to creating drop shadow effects in SVG. The SVG specification includes an example of this.

Comment: `-webkit-filter: drop-shadow()` is the way to go for sure. See the answer by @hitautodestruct.

Comment: @clayzermk1 if you want it to work only in webkit.... then yeah. We're lookin for a more solid solution, methinks, and I think this is also no longer supported.

Comment: @jbeard4 link broken, better maybe have the content pasted here.

Comment: Submited link point to *`Removed: Filter Effects
This chapter is no longer part of the SVG specification`*!!

Comment: This is a non-answer.