# Need to make a css curve on CSS

Tags: css, styled-components

Hi guys i need to make a curve like dat on css.
Any ideas to do dat ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0o4Y.png)

Comment: It would be nice if you share more about what you want to do. From the image, it looks that is "curve" is more complex than just adding a border-radius. You probably need other tags to develop that idea.

Comment: here is a post with lots of tries and examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350457/sigmoid-curve-shape-with-css