# <SVG> Filter issue with Safari

Tags: firefox, svg, safari, svg-filters

I have looked around for a previous answer to this issue, but none of the solutions I have found resolve the issue.

My `<path>` with a `filter` applied to it doesn't render in Safari (I'm running 11.0.2) or Firefox (57.0.4).

Here is my code:

```
<!-- html -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 88 88" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <filter id="glow" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="sourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"/>
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncA type="linear" slope=".21"/>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <path d="M69.45584,18.54416a36,36,0,1,1-50.91168,0"/>
    <path d="M18.54416,18.54416a36,36,0,0,1,50.91168,0" filter="url(#glow)"/>
</svg>

/* css / scss */
path {
    fill: none;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    @include rem(stroke-width, 8); // 8px

    @include pseudo(nth-of-type(unquote('2n+1'))) {
        stroke: rgba(38, 38, 38, .03)
    }

    @include pseudo(nth-of-type(unquote('2n'))) {
        stroke: rgb(0, 131, 202);
    }
}
```

This `path` with the `filter` applied to it renders in Chrome. As soon as I remove the reference to the `filter` the `path` shows up with all css applied.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your are trying to merge in a filter primitive called "coloredBlur", which doesn't exist.  In this situarion, browsers are supposed to use the previous primitive result. Chrome obviously is. Perhaps Safari is not. Just a guess tho.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau: Are you suggesting I just remove that `<feMergeNode/>` and it should work? Because that hasn't resolved the issue. It's also removed the outer glow from Chrome.

Comment: Never mind. I think I found the actual problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such input as `sourceAlpha`. The correct name is `SourceAlpha`.

I can't currently test on Safari, but it fixes the problem in Firefox.

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-width: 8;
  stroke: rgba(38, 38, 38, .03);
  stroke: rgb(0, 131, 202);
}

path:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  stroke: rgba(38, 38, 38, .03);
}

path:nth-of-type(2n) {
  stroke: rgb(0, 131, 202);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 88 88" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <filter id="glow" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"/>
            <feComponentTransfer result="blur">
                <feFuncA type="linear" slope=".21"/>
            </feComponentTransfer>
             <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="blur"/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <path d="M69.45584,18.54416a36,36,0,1,1-50.91168,0"/>
    <path d="M18.54416,18.54416a36,36,0,0,1,50.91168,0" filter="url(#glow)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I see I was missing the `result` attribute for `<feComponentTransfer>`. The only issue I have is that now the `path` `#glow` is dark? It was the same color as the `stroke` in Chrome.

Comment: I think that must be a bug in Chrome. In the spec `SourceAlpha` is defined as a black input with the alpha of the original graphic.  It shouldn't be blue.  You need to recolour it. See the high score answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965196/svg-color-of-the-shadow

Comment: With that solution, you won't need the `feComponentTransfer` step you are currently using.

Comment: Actually not a bug. Chrome is following the new SVG2 behaviour of defaulting to `SourceGraphic` for non-existent input names

Comment: Thank you @PaulLeBeau. I found something helpful in the lower voted answer—I swapped the `in` attribute to `SourceGraphic` on the `<feGaussianBlur>` (see my suggested edit). Appreciate your help. Very informative.