# SVG gradients all around

Tags: svg

I have designing a progress bar, around which I need to show a gradient glow. 
I am using linear gradient something like this:

```
<linearGradient id="settingsProgressBarInnerGlow" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%">
<stop stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0"/>
<stop stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0.2" stop-opacity="0.1"/>
<stop stop-color="#E6F7FC" offset="0.5" stop-opacity="0.4"/>
<stop stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0.8" stop-opacity="0.1"/>
<stop stop-color="#ffffff" offset="1" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
```

But this is giving me gradient something like this.[image: (Linear gradient only on top and bottom)What I am getting using linear]
I want the gradient all round the bar like this.[image: (Gradient all around)What I need actually]

Can someone help me with best answers?

Comment: Have you considered using filters instead of gradients? See e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630008/how-can-i-create-a-glow-around-a-rectangle-with-svg

Comment: I fail to see the gradient. This looks like a job for box shadow to me, from these images...

Answer (score 0):

From your images, it looks like you can do what you want with `box-shadow` property. Svgs are in boxes sortof by default.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/WYUen/)

HTML

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bar {
    position: relative;    
    width: 400px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: #333;
}

.bar .progress {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #559adb;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #559adb;
}
```

You can have mulitple box-shadows too by putting a comma after the color and defining a second - which could be helpful in creating a gradient effect.

```
.bar .progress {
    box-shadow: 
        0 0 20px 0 #559adb,
        0 0 20px 0 red;  /* etc */
}
```