# How to create a gaussian blur effect using "stdDeviation" in SVG?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I´m trying to apply a gaussian blur to a png image in Firefox. For WebKit browsers I use the CSS3 filter property. In CSS, I use a 2px blur but how can I create the same effect in SVG with "stdDeviation"?
Thank you!

Comment: Pretty similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3

Answer (score 2):

Just apply an feGaussianBlur filter to an SVG `<image>` element using the filter attribute.

```
<defs>
<filter id="Gaussian_Blur">
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5"/>
</filter>
</defs>
```