# SVG filter that highlights a path upwards (image sample provided)

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to highlight the countries of a svg map in a specific manner. 
This is the result I want to achieve:

#### Before

[image: before]

#### After

[image: after]

Using the drop shadow technique provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6094674, I was able to obtain a small relief effect, but I think this might not be the correct direction.
How should I approach this?

Comment: i think using `feOffset` ([as suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6094674/547020)) is a perfectly valid solution, maybe just drop the `feGaussianBlur`.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a shadow effect, which is fine. But if you want a true relief effect that works for all shapes (even fiddly ones with thin horizontal lines), then you'll need to composite multiple copies of the SourceGraphic, incrementally offset in y once for each pixel.  Alternatively, you can use lighting primitives and some fancy compositing.