# Highlight SVG group elements like <rect> with CSS / Javascript /jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to highlight the SVG element on hover as glowing element.

I know we can use it using filters.

But, I wonder is there any easier way to achieve that by using CSS or JavaScript or JQuery

I know following code works on Chrome:

```
-webkit-svg-shadow: 0 0 7px red;
```

But I cannot rely on this code as it doesnt work on Safari or Firefox.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG drop shadow using css3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work, just use a css-box shadow on the svg element`:hover`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dZ2AA/1/)

**HTML**

```
<svg height=100 width=100 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></svg>
```

**CSS**

```
svg{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
svg:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px yellow;
}
```

Comment: It works awesome with SVG element. But, my question was confusing. What I am trying to do is highlight a particular SVG element in a group. Like <rect>. i applied this property to it but it did not work : Any ideas>?

Comment: Ahhh... then what you're looking for is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3