# How to generate a shadow for an arbitrary polygon?

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry

I have a list of points that make up a polygon. I would like to know if there's an easy way to generate a shadow for this polygon in 2d, assuming there is only one light that's very far away. I have tried many methods, and even tried writing my own algorithm, but had limited success.
I want to achieve an effect similar to this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0epC0.png
or in other words, similar to the feMorphology filter in SVG.

Comment: Doesn't this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3 answer your question?

Comment: It's not going to be used on the web or SVG, but on a simple 2d game engine I am making. For performance reasons, I need to precalculate these shadows beforehand.

Comment: The algorithms for SVG filters are in the SVG specification.

Comment: Google "webgl javascript library", have a number of javascript 3d and 2d library already written.

Comment: Your example is not a normal drop shadow, it is a 3D extrusion. Filters or feMorphology won't help you, you'll have to do some hard math.