# SVG gaussian blur on text under Google Chrome

Tags: text, svg, filter

I'm trying to make a text effect with a drop shadow gaussian blur on my svg.
Under firefox it's look good, but under chrome it's horrible, as you can see below.

[image]

What is strange is taht when zooming (ctrl + mousewheel) at the max level possible, it's suddenly looks good, but at intermediate zooming level, it's still horrible.

My code to generate this example is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="200px" heigth="200px">
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" />
        <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur" />
        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode />
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <text x="50" y="50" style="filter:url(#dropshadow)">This is a test</text>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I've taken the drop shadow code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3).

Note that I'm using one of the last version of Firefox (33.1) and of Chrome (Version 38.0.2125.122 m).

Comment: Possibly this bug? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422176

Comment: Yest it's look like this bug (regression). It seems to be already patched but waiting for a new version of chrome to use this patch.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't correct behaviour at all. It looks like Chrome is failing to render the alpha channel correctly for text at small font sizes.

This is what I get if I just extract the alpha channel from text sized at 18, 36 and 72pt:

[image: bad chrome]

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
  <filter id="f" width="200%" height="200%">
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in="SourceAlpha" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="#eee" />
  <text font-size="18" x="5" y="25" style="filter:url(#f)">Small</text>
  <text font-size="36" x="5" y="75" style="filter:url(#f)">Medium</text>
  <text font-size="72" x="5" y="165" style="filter:url(#f)">Large</text>
</svg>
```

> **EDIT:** This isn't an answer, so I've flagged as community wiki.