# How to apply drop-shadow filter via CSS to SVG specific element/path

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I'd like to apply a drop-shadow filter to a specific element/path inside an inline placed SVG via CSS, I **don't** need the whole graphic to be shadowed, just an element inside it.

```css
.shadow {
  fill: red;
  
  -webkit-filter: 
    drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.7) );
          filter: 
    drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.7) );
}
```

```html
  <svg height="150" width="150">
    <g>
<path d="M0,0 C-72,132 -72,-26 100,100"></path>
    </g>
    <g class="shadow" >
    <circle class="shadow" cx="100" cy="100" r="20"></circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

As you can see above, I'm trying to apply a drop-shadow to the red circle element of the SVG, but it's not working.

Searching around I haven't found any specific info on this, [only few comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3#comment54428619_13624469) in other SVG related questions simply stating that it doesn't work on single SVG elements, but without much explanations.

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by [@azeós](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460182/how-to-apply-drop-shadow-filter-via-css-to-svg-specific-element-path#comment56662795_34460182) in the comments, it is rendering correctly with Firefox (v. 43.0.2) so it's a Chrome specific issue. Is there anyway to make this crossbrowser without fiddling out with the SVG code as suggested in the comments?

Comment: Just curious, why not the SVG filters to create a shadow?

Comment: Like Harry suggests, I think your best option for a drop shadow is filters in the svg code http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_feoffset.asp

Comment: Yea should have specified in the question, I'd like to avoid messing with the SVG code due to workflow. Is this re<lly the only viable option?

Comment: I'm seeing the shadow... Waterfox 40.1.0, which browser are you using? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13624469/1095101

Comment: Oh nice I'm using chrome, I can see the shadow too on Firefox. I guess it's a Chrome business then. What is the specific issue with chrome? I've updated the quesiton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a shadow selectively by doing color selection on the object you want to shadow, creating a shadow and then merging it under the original graphic. But you have to do it via the SVG filter trapdoor in CSS Filters - which doesn't work in IE. (So ... hacky, but possible)

Spec is here: w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement

Demo toy is here:
https://beta.observablehq.com/@gitmullany/filter-effects-using-svg-color-matrices

That matrix doubles the opacity of all red values, zeros out the opacity of everything else and then subtracts 1. The effect is to only leave things at 100% opacity that are rgb(255,0,0)

```css
#mySVG {
   filter: url(#selective-shadow);
}

.shadow {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg>
 <defs>
   <filter id="selective-shadow">
     <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 
                                          0 0 0 0 0
                                          0 0 0 0 0 
                                          2 0 0 0 -1"/>
     <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3"/>
     <feOffset dy="2" dx="2"/>
     <feMerge>
       <feMergeNode/>
       <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
     </feMerge>         
   </filter>
 </defs>
</svg>



<svg height="150" width="150" id="mySVG">
    <g>
<path d="M0,0 C-72,132 -72,-26 100,100"></path>
    </g>
    <g class="shadow" >
    <circle class="shadow" cx="100" cy="100" r="20"></circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Oh wow that's some advanced SVG hackery, and as far as I can see it works! Very nice! May I ask where the documentation for that matrix grid stuff is? :)

Comment: spec is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement Demo toy is here: https://beta.observablehq.com/@gitmullany/filter-effects-using-svg-color-matrices. That matrix doubles the opacity of all red values, zeros out the opacity of everything else and then subtracts 1. The effect is to only leave things at 100% opacity that are rgb(255,0,0)

Comment: Holy SVG!! I didn't know you can do such things with SVGs, damn guess I need quite some update on this subject x)
Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

**Updated 2020-04:** I did some experiments on this issue because I too couldn't find any information on this and the results are pretty inconsistent.

**The TL;DR: SVG drop-shadows are very inconsistent but HTML drop-shadows reliably work (outside of IE11).** If you want SVG drop-shadows, [you're going to have use a polyfill](https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill) or just do the drop-shadow within the SVG itself.

Codepen experiment:
http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/GoNoMq

### Chrome 81 + Canary 83:

Neither Chrome nor edge Canary respect `filter` or `-webkit-filter` properly in the context of an SVG object drop-shadow but do work on a simple `div`.

[image]

### Firefox 75 + Firefox 53 (pre-quantum):

Looks pretty good for both SVG and HTML objects.

[image]

### Safari 13+

Safari briefly had dropshadows on earlier versions but has dropped them again.

[image]

### Safari 10.1 - 11

Safari has fixed this issue in the 10.1 (and maybe the 10.0) series.

[image]

### Safari 9.x

SVG CSS dropshadow does not show and the `div` dropshadow has less opacity for some reason

[image]

### Edge (Chromium version)

No SVG dropshadows but the HTML ones work well.

[image]

### IE11

Nothing.

[image]

Comment: Interesting research, thank you! I can't test myself atm the polyfill, can you confirm that it's working on chrome too?

Comment: I havent tried the polyfill, I'll have to do it tomorrow as I'm done for the day in my time zone. Let me know if you give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

In [this](https://codepen.io/ChemBioScripting/pen/wEXrjB) CodePen I added different *drop-shadows* to `path` and `text` generated dynamically. [Here](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/EaMQBj) I found a cross-browser solution that you can apply to a `class`, for example, instead of `#robbie img` (in the second link):

```
#robbie img { filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";   filter: url(#drop-shadow);   -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));   filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)); }
```

In the [first CodePen](https://codepen.io/ChemBioScripting/pen/wEXrjB) I commented another alternative way that does not use the *classes*, but it uses `#numbers_dropshadows_filter` and `#strokes_dropshadows_filter` defined in `<defs></defs>`.

Cheers