# SVG pixelated when using CSS3 drop-shadow filter with transform: scale

Tags: css, svg

I'm displaying an world map with an inline SVG, and wanted a nice, subtle drop shadow around the country borders. I achieved this with the CSS3 `filter` property:

```
#map.shadow g#world {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25));
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25));
}
```

This totally worked... until I needed to be able to zoom the map. I'm using `transform: scale()` for the zoom (applied to the container, as there are marker elements & junk on top of the map), but this seems to 'bitmapize' the clean, crisp SVG. If I remove the `filter` drop-shadow, it goes back to being nice an crisp again.

I've tried applying the shadow a couple of different ways, including an SVG filter (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6094674/988246)) & `translateZ(0)` on the element, but the result is always the same - ugly, pixelated countries. For reference:

[image]

I'm assuming this is because the `filter: drop-shadow()` values are in `px`, and since I'm scaling up the div for the zoom (to, say `1.5`, or 150%), that's also scaling the filter's `px`... but I've got no idea how to solve it (using relational units like `em` or `vh` doesn't seem to make a difference).

I've made up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5j6kud8L/) with an example (for code brevity, the map only contains Greenland).

Any idea how to keep my drop-shadow *and* nice crisp borders on the SVG?

*Edit:* as requested, here's a snippet:

```js
var zoomLevel = 1;

$('#controls').on('click', '.zoombutton', function(e) {
    var zoomDelta = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-delta'));
    zoomLevel += zoomDelta;

    $('#map').css({'transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')'});
});

$('#controls').on('click', '.shadow', function(e) {
    $('#map').toggleClass('shadow');
});
```

```css
#controls {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#map.shadow g#world {
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25));
 filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controls">
    <button type="button" class="zoombutton" data-delta="0.25">+</button>
    <button type="button" class="zoombutton" data-delta="-0.25">-</button>
    <button type="button" class="shadow">Toggle shadow</button>
</div>

<div id="map" class="shadow">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1009" height="665" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0  1009 665" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <g id="world" class="shadow">
   <path id="US" fill="#1976D2" d="M391.637.873l2.697 1.497 1.426 1.724.299-.057 1.933.657 1.835.817 3.051 2.11.428.687-.33.56-.758.384-3.899.682-7.073.833-4.047 1.605-1.287.082-.112 2.358.55.128.901-.315 3.17-2.365 1.186-.392 2.213.198 2.873.892 1.159-.313 2.067.233 2.417-.682 2.855-1.481.781 3.29 1.052 3.227.833-.354.713.18.241 1.046.39.441.808-.236 2.475.907 1.699 1.619.64.749.307 1.062.174.846-.267 1.035-1.062 1.828-1.343 1.661-1.812 1.267-2.088.789-16.045 2.611-.543.615-.322 1.559.214 2.004.75.311 1.752-1.123 3.031-1.072 2.227.051 5.324.915 1.571 2.369.831 3.574 1.842-.796.394-.611.29-1.065.231-1.151.173-1.236.193-.847.214-.451.459-.378 1.057-.457 2.772-.445.667.127.479 1.717.104.995.035 1.287-.015 1.574-.065 1.852-.236 1.812-.767 3.118-.617 1.673-.666 1.196-1.275 2.696-.442.713-1.402 3.075-.348 1.406-.021 1.021.241.194.407-.959.151-.688.262-.724 2.066-1.923.443-.54 1.352-2.326.863-.879.709-.927.376-.66 2.077-4.757 1.083-1.451 1.137-.003.201 2.449 1.363.375.592-.105.951.59.417.484.709.246.731.572.645-.615.188-.387.623-1.765.842-1.579.78-1.993.259-.487.41-.443.426-.175 1.16-.947.294-.066.626.3 2.766.156 1.509.488 2.101 1.347 1.464.733.678.646.987 1.377.796 1.429.37.417-.014.45-.275.619-1.972 2.146-.646 1.419-1.866 2.642-.912.898-.991.351-1.103.084-.716.374-.106.355.51 1.07.224.758-.032.671-.537.99-.203.223-1.938.73-.978 1.232-1.276.149-.902-.14-1.24 1.315.485 1.062.444.458 1.381.958.013.548-.66 1.101-.901 1.289-1.065.888-.4.132-.505-.223-.466.048-1.026.408-.977.065-1.745-.577-.944-.67-.497-.232-.626.064-.241.271-.987 1.593-.484 1.078-.311 1.096-.133 1.186.045 1.274.12.868.195.468.234.283.41.148.902-.14.354.08.108.254.195.802-.034.752-.164 1.052-.126 1.219-.09 1.382.048.75.365.164.171-.054.199.246.226.543.17.573.113.602-.059.495-.233.388-.525.437-1.293.859-.131.261-.102.52-.072.778-.156.705-.24.63-.218.375-.419.166-.549.022-.617.36-1.454 2.085-.022.23.544.663-.023.578-.671 2.459-.184 1.205-.146 1.638-.239 1.369-.333 1.106-.328 1.268-.322 1.424.05 1.085.423.751.559-.607.695-1.982.756-.864.816.271.711.396.908.779.76.484.656.635.271.533.272.749.002.471-.481.253-.159-.081-1.204-1.235-.586-.309-.778.372-.678.559.609 2.231.651 1.016 1.188.461.62.484.453.617.354.3.475-.132.639-.606.891-.033.402.301.291.56.131 1.042-.029 1.514-.097 1.131-.165.756-.321 1.008-.268.183-.377-.055-.351-.206-.325-.359-.492-.28-.989-.303-1-.66-.56-.163-1.185.084-1.278.418-.05.547-1.838 1.897-.377-.026-.51-.649-.714-.624-.418.004-.618.79-.154.305.008.287.455.677.185.155.235.13.817.162.355.177.334 2.076.53 1.27.227.258.2.093.65-.046.836-.427.292.342.616.417.36.104.438-.017.493.158.676 1.155-.266 1.444.423 1.147.676 1.175.16.428.065.772.015.507.051.463.086.416.089.814.093 1.206-.024.978-.143.754-.282.545-.42.338-.343-.089-.266-.516-.375-.552-.483-.588-.803-.069-1.182 1.732-.527.086-.429.171-.457.749-.673.449-.594-.178-1.043-.87.379.582.542.679.338.351.249.076.273-.081.394-.277.889-.771.235-.118.199.055.163.228.188.661.211 1.088-.027.921-.266.755-.228.483-.189.212v.167l.497.192.703-.979.223-1.226.322-1.425.569-.477.644.477.52 1.331.735 2.421.31.25.394.575.174.703-.046.829-.084.6-.122.372-.152.236-.274.15-.504.12-1.126-.251-.586-.006.073.808-1.186.692-1.337.271-1.266-.54-1.051-.833.345-1.171.197-1.31-.508-.873-.111-.019.175 1.347-.147.513-.574.623-.405.287-.036.167.199.145.129.278.061.411-.068.414-.198.417-.108.349-.018.282.181.342.381.401.413.198 1.935.086.775.215 1.838.941.082.288-.311 1.669-.17 1.588-.357.289-1.934.068-.623.246-.912.722-.876.862-.454.006-1.798-.752-.689-.504-1.48-1.434-1.114-2.206-.511.921-.313.438-.323.227-.311.035-.3-.157-.34-.347-.571-.808-.681-.803-.477-.383-.018.109.282.473.412.544 1.043 1.589.367.399-.037.283-.658.251-.8.54-.391.396-.604.958-.21.148-.904.24-.298-.058-.668-.526-1.007-.345-.593-.307-.824-.558.284.61 1.587.925.174.297-.325.552-.199.201-.378.042-.557-.115-.57.023-.583.162-.25.206.082.251.139.228.196.206.184-.002.444-.623.336-.044.889.154.899-.487.648-.211.486-.054 1.767-.749.367-.842.593-.339 1.318-.26 1.276.133.656.109.531.798.712.563.594.64.696.21.403.847 1.128.941.718.202.443.446.036 1.877.047.804-.191 2.206-.577.504.115 1.148-.151.922-.573-.349-.587-.607-1.407-.946-1.309-.611-.509-.556-.599-.432-.813-1.768-.529-2.225-.232-1.111-.445-.062-.572.298-.5.315-.239.537-1.698.736-.617.502-.352-.015-1.268.754.508.36.237.045.513-.203.308-.26 1.156-.714.928-.123.337-.309.709-.442.481-.117.067.112.052.202.339 2.703-.142.712-.382.308-.817.503-.212.244.241.426.768-.401.498-.437.266.159.435.667.491.341 1.248 1.018.591.558.832.537.94.742.245.261.859.383.184.131.355 1.296.296.144.855.082-.15.5-.835 1.105-.432.352-.107.216.041.386.025.645.174 1.18.196-1.092.137-.518.183-.155.18-.023.584-.492.587.264.152 1.239.075 1.148-.051.986.064 1.521-.022.511.139.441.144 1.816.144.542-.289.484-.893.21-.353-.238-.883.08-.0001-.426-.043-.49-.003-.343-.059-.311-.042-1.798-.25.446-.015.365-.066.371-.153 1.927-.228.47-.707-.113-.696.069-.385-.071-1.302-.875-.504-.796-.446-1.203-.275-1.131-.104-1.059-.313-.866-.52-.671-.614-.545-.708-.419-.622-.542-.536-.666-.589-.52-.644-.372-.916-.16-1.339.059-.904-.42-.215.036-.211.217.155.617 1.038.282.8.064 1.061-.04.649.158.238.355.164.63.09.902-.21.712-.763.787-.402.368-1.175.704-.398.156-.98.048-.753-.067-.991-.35-.562-.071-1.163-.047L396 176.287l.3.375.493.212.347.252.036.477-.125.705-.129.491-.213.368-.763.694-.316.219-1.422.723-.099.139.333-.019.899-.256.259.007 1.476.625 1.176-.037 2.382-.577.196.011.156.091.158.216.16.342-.192.331-.544.318-.847.313-.367.211-.351.32-.653.767-.191.792.687.3.309-.38.364-.847.328-.499.773-.339.944.172.729-.201 1.49-.843.267-.052 2.192.483 1.987.945 1.048.346 1.387.204 2.494-.093.219.148-.081.333-.145.281-.416.391-.505.258-.312.073-.266.184-.597.18-.153.146.207.636-.098.098-.526.011-.886.413-.727-.029-.152.06.138.153.146.295.155.436-.085.311-.326.185-.247.06-.853-.259-.138.039.125.187.071.284.017.382-.209.319-.436.257-.813.706-.354.201-.746.166-.157.092.303.538-.034.215-.504.579-.763.36-.104.194-.07.52-.056.207-.202.297-.724.564-.513.28-.254.229-.315.382-.397.202-.479.023-.454.143-.746.405-.52.134-1.642.696-.772.111-.668.248-1.375.661-.655.212-.454.251-.496.072-.807-.163-.435-.006-.268.099-.245.202-.405.552-.344.042-1.128-.437.023.198.298.473-.014.334-.671.339-.361.086-.533-.139-.705-.366-.905-.766-1.109-1.175-.534-.399.039.379.124.37.209.359.042.26-.124.161-.163.081-.203.0001-.035.091.331.558.261.571-.024.54-.31.51-.266.298-.222.088-1.317 1.262-.367.159-.167.155-.137.232-.383 1.035-.155.315-.308.409-.129.071-.037.167.056.262-.085.436-.225.608-.767 1.668-.618 1.542-.271.502-.198.212-.125-.076-.307.039-.149.269-.135.485-.147.369-.159.253-1.24 1.088-.319.201-.287-.127-.339.049-.703-.573-.122-.211-.454-.473.015.247.076.136.063.199.159.244.352 1.277-.278.261-.249.297-.635.501-.687.836-.253.233-.057-.681.029-.204-.388-.331.012.238-.04.222-.281.882-.078.152-.139-.034-.302.162-.309-.077-.263-.4-.104-.208-.478.571-.232-.015-.039.478-.225.435-.297.188-.415-.015-.254.257-.563-.275-.13-.517.446-.711.126-.294-.082-.363.108-.47.852-1.499.577-.764-.033-.137-.784-.167-.685-.263-.667-.09-.295.089.47.44.665.426-.327.406-.282.43-.292 1.165-.187.475-.725-.545-.343-.185.218.605.635.572.041.188-.004.677-1.216.595-1.269.09-.911.168-1.537.204h-.597l-.051.228 1.503 1.036.219.189-.209.355-.311.22-.488.757-.255.26-.632.357-1.163-.398-.598.178-.572-.125-.012.435.171.317.173.785.384-.061.488-.247.377.593.248 1 .433.505.192.39.078.367-.27.365-.559.514-.62.096.034.406-.268.291-.569-.085-.266-.204-.276-.096-1.132-.109 1.14.78.405.362.18-.214.395-.052.583.198-.097 1.306.255 1.051.031.235-.621.626-.001.583-.37.162-.398-.037-.021.637-.27.396.048.248.077.221-.246.402-.222.488-.318.426-.168-.044-.505.028-.607-.036-.492-.554-.204-.185-.23-.121.088.357.138.214.454.4.836.493-.026.349-.223.151-.521.945-.185.021-.234.243-.722-.082-.303-.097-.891.062-.303-.083-.26.04.242.266.51.239.58.24.882.181-.032.342-.221.28.127.417-.099.298-.042.354-.206.82.24.56.261.273-.03.359.123.572-.392.509-.325-.019-.463.114-.154.224.734.211-.067.379-.2.474-.21 1.021-.427 1.738-.2 1.71-.917 1.394-.325.039-.082.055-.447-.071-.702-.321-.543-.106-.367-.004-.047.16.304.258.465.108.372.171.667.159.232.308.159.328-.023.18-.0001.212.119 1.139-.314.392-.24.354-.833-.049-.145-.124-.804-.373.049.175.582.506.203.252-.136.052-.235.019-.327.17-.591-.092.033-.255.112-.263-.27.045-.301.133-.175-.049-.146.015-.083-.132-.114-.515.136-.259.487-.672.155-.362-.135-.165-.348.388-.359.615-.16.371-.225.072-.559-.187-1.591-.861.047-.525-.015-.436.464-.055.337-.19.302-.233.34-.425.312-.704-.04-.054-.915.898-.563.299-.272.055-.136-.132-.453-.288-.294-.131-.671-.214-.119-.115-.197-.092-.268-.92.346-1.124.238-.328.151-.38.085-.505-.059-.216-.202.074-.094.173.015.271-.116.188-.8.431-.802.349-.38.33-.247.257-.193.252-.295-.022-.407.051-.279.164-.408-.101-.266-.243-.321-.028-.36.117-.249-.001.021.165.166.405-.275.027-.522.016-.263-.118-.206-.154-.171-.215.103-.282.84-.518.381-.301-.249-.103-.806.093-.134-.078-.54.047.023-.775-.131-.193-.009-.091-.187-.217-.177-.054-.11-.078-.912-.175-.119-.435-.063-.449-.174-.559-.437-.146-.236-.243.188-.249.082-.316-.202-.145-.129-.223.019-.145-.164-.393-.049-.307.188-.289.516-.327.167-.132.086-.143.592-.241-.504-.17-.315-.026-.23.08-.212.32-.198.212-.772.069-.114-.11-.054-.452.044-.349.321-.492-.37-.244-.339-.08-.385-.229-.356-.242-.306-.282-.298-.333-.095-.042.107-.349.061-.288.009-.62-.12-.258.267-.532.359-.583.794-.869-.84.419-.69.911-.146.042-.051-.165-.262-.591-.197-.162-.088-.178-.393-.317-.17-.244-.242-.472-.344-.564-.489-1.117-.79-1.295-.195-.732.245-.933-.271-.646.75-.3 1.073-.337.557-.281.321-.084.682-.052.228-.283-.379.072-.255-.037-.016-.132.094-.235.061-.304-.13.055-.667.523-.986.414-.77.23-.125-.012-.27.139-.155.04-.12-.04-.272-.396-.073-.259.489-.705.365-.966.483-.635.341-.08.571.034.201.056-.064-.377.024-.183.463-.22.54-.098.384.069.242.444.311.816.419.275-.019-.391-.217-.505-.081-.778-.276-.329-.221-.162-.612.079-.368-.572-.083-.21-.009-.28-.368-.824-.118-.414-.195-.552-.104-.03.132.695.172.487.246 1.066.122.428-.165.338-.311.334-.275.199-.65.238.14-.52.089-.512-.327.182-.304.372-.105.514-.195.465-.579 1.137-.228.628-.216.309-.246.085-.213-.245-.181-.577-.085-.453-.001-1.18.023-.553-.099-.748-.313-1.753-.066-.629-.529-.335-.008-.108-.138-.36-.107-.361.088-.132.126-.095.791-.534.586-.6.701-.945.286-.294 1.028-.227.456-.031-.004-.169-.153-.067-.694.044-.925.38-.159.137-.405.589-.312.321-.878.731h-.57l-.588-.876-.657.168-.443-.058-.129-.132-.098-1.204.357-1.415-.386-.014-.08-.057-.204-.324-.133-.097.099-.172.951-.676 1.423-1.334.612-.527.378-.228.286-.261.348-.568.115-.249.194-.201.409-.227.447-.344.725-.776.095-.288-.158-.067-.339.266-.689.71-.492.398-1.679 1.771-.715.64-.389.408-.302.388-.319.276-.338.165-.72.123-.354.143-.213-.104-.094-.828.072-.492-.034-.487.18-.7.267-.497.112-.271.047-.186.55-.517.303-.229.214-.52 1.221-.185.315.019.167-.07.125-.151-.121-.117-.366-.083-.973.016-.899-.089-.41-.09-.198.052-.327-.152-.357-.291-.554-1.072.222-1.386.019-.666.704-.585.376-.194.534-.442.713-.754.851-.462.434-.086.36.066 1.332.655.685.128.602-.157.755.229 1.336.938.258-.139-.075-.227-1.49-.993.008-.298.381-.078.407-.29-.229-.172-.99.149-.286.238-.96.123-.501-.202-.45-.101-.675-.432-.565.141-.357.17-.631.161-.228.115-1.233 1.352-.519.28-.369-.092.259-.878.075-.348v-.379l.107-.521.632-.997.397-1.098.168-.685.311-.077.424.101 1.274.444 1.06.528.782.141.514.015.22-.168.174-.293.067-.203.05-.416.059-.148.172-.182.351-.635.107-.453-.115-.265-.234.027-.457.174-.062.072.008.142-.441.701-.481.161-1.107.234-.505.017-.898-.325-.136-.127-.093-.239-1.102.054-.329.072-.262-.031.128-.416.348-.463.488-1.515.409-.39.812-.364.847.059 1.465 1.177.442.102.405-.095.969-.393.178-.16.349-.489.407-.84-.02-.199-.625.47-.333.126h-.282l.262-1.542.102-1.19.098-.297.821.089 1.122-.162.267-.262-.004-.116-.45-.159-.217-.335-.377.106-.505.223-.634-.025.053-.517.465-1.089.048-.499.181-1.001.019-.516.235-.503.733-.359.308-.215.017-.236-.439-.901.111-.25.345-.228.128-.167-.088-.104-.317-.1-.488.2-.54.096-.478-.301-.374-.145-.236.045-.643.515-.225.017-.278-.143-1.842-.446-.229-.158-.66-.775-.544-.514-.724-.563-.939-.429-1.153-.294-.69-.277-.34-.392-.583-.865-.443-.724-.083-.359.26-.445.265-.32.499-.263.861.087.462.117.509.251.385.047.799-.071.813.16.481.176.632.366 1.744 1.549.728.535.316.064 1.305.57.209-.011.534-.267.053-.173-.18-.171-.576-.133-.676-.632-.419-.503-.048-.835.055-.47.105-.214.074-.723-.392-.431-.273-.136-.727-.631-.061-.157.349-.074.342.043.733.32.384.044.28-.125.032-.129-.446-.364-.558-.653-1.166-.097-.756.074-.483-.225-.514-.366-.331-.094-.675.23-.341.029-.311-.081-.307-1.16.082-.349.241-.151.182-.377.127-.395.4-.387 2.195-.865.554-.646-.024-.1-.374.12-.478.292-.319.06-1.292-.377-.202.086-.523.541-.71.585-.327-.036-.438-.346-.069-.247-.032-.297.481-.408.154-.216.311-.583-.016-.289-.531.159-.069-.269.008-.461-.051-.585-.13-.58-.436-.895-.181-.23-.149-.333-.329-1.221.095-.307.292-.233.056-.107-.697.193-.076.212.131.313.094.416.056.518.097.452.252.494.202.259.329.684.144.749-.042.393-.255.399-.412.429-.125.355-.056.353-.321.326-.197-.122-.156-.019.184.58.119.592-.143.591-.381.357-.207.011-.407.289-1.042.151-.363-.071-.665-.293-.789-.16-.313-.396-.41-.723-.207-.65-.004-.577.111-.421.226-.266.272-1.707.384-1.391.967-1.446.276-.526.091-.283-.0001-.216-.156-.137-1.189 1.795-.733.19-.219-.402.066-.716.131-.167.593.068.23-.4-.371-.606-.395-.16-.092-.153.406-.464.94.034.212-.325.34-.351.378-.654.141-.552.032-.475-.082-.384-.008-.386.064-.388-.099-.43-.261-.472-.581-.462-.171.522-.181.214-.254.048-.234-.22-.245-.079-.24-.196-.25-.063-.097-.158-.063-.444-.005-.566.282-.266.393-.209.263-.397.173-.577.025-.633-.123-.688-.319-.621-.591.604-.232.148-.053-.432-.082-.32-.248-.436-.327-.318-.314-.212-.014-.323.074-.365.14-.426.181-.893.199.08.166-.082-.096-.741-.16-.625-.188-.357-.007-.155-.043-.182-.145-.441-.163-.324-.284-.921-.205-.353-.263-.183-.283-.001-.455.244-.839.28-.665.133-.111-.073.333-.351.49-.366.648-.249.189-.612-.07-.531.027-.505-.178-.533.173-.296.59-.299.268-.046.266-.381-.748-.923-.784-.607-.196-.248-.172-.408-.148-.57-.242-.572-.334-.576-.488-.557-1.258-1.024-.432-.71-.398-1.092-.199-.468-.207-.347-.876-.816-.106-.362.905-.968.088-.388-.37-1.185-.378-.872-.412-.311-.613-.16-.562-.39-.511-.62-.51-.455-.764-.434-1.278-1.121-1.97-1.208-.88-.71-.524-.259-.69-.066-1.335-.667-1.122-.214-.692.098-.226-.111-.512-.681-.801-.392-.414.149-.514.73-.62.717-.33.097-.49-.655-.247-.459-.236-.157-.225.148-.438.603-.417.434-.617.514-.493.246-.633.06-.159.186-.244.008-.328-.168-.308-.334-.287-.501-.253-.271-.22-.04-.505.26-.639.762-.292.183-.245-.079-.3-.237-.601-.608-.333.059-.242.213.067.504.563 1.19.503.843-.425.099-3.712-1.141-.473-.276-.683-.695-.568-.428-.967-1.111-.745-.604-.247-.474-.065-.327.237-.443 1.5-1.503.573-.305 1.166-.365.275-.229.092-.182-.306-.329-1.527.118-1.36-.22-1.184-.607-.206-.202-.201-.373-.195-.544.044-.611.284-.679.167-.468.049-.254-1.488 1.672-.608.582-.482-.178-.338-.275-.166-.307.006-.339.055-.248.103-.155-.787-.694-.354-.547-.038-.566.279-.586.273-.426.267-.267.728-.232 2.658-.445 1.903.427.648-1.419.438-.455 1.28-.475 1.97-.066 1.391.263.652.335.888.737.051-.222-.214-.666-.015-.555.359-.969.165-.611-.112-.639-.39-.667-.69-.86-.372-.071-.413.208-.496.477-1.031 1.196-.487.249-.812.063-.449-.15-.434-.179-.678-.633-.247-.119-.3.278-.352.673-.339.47-.327.268-.305.116-.426-.055-1.755-1.044-.396-.467-.023-.71-.539-.691-.609-.121-.074-.232.772-1.073.576-.44-.092-.133-.836-.023-.564.573-.323.097-.743.016-.78-.287-.332-.251-.344-.578-.386-.326-1.165-.496-.263-.271-.249-.451-.952-1.283-.576-.949-.075-.541.665-1.167.029-.271-.285-.507-.119-.375.098-.519.582-1.155.216-.314 1.043-.683 1.045-.998.38-.225.339-.052 1.373.06.425-.247.361-.49.593-.498 1.237-.759 2.75-1.154.179-.137.016-.22-.247-.599-.052-.29.563-.54 1.271-.855.869-.413.559-.03.451-.185.633-.542.358-.096 2.163-.213.957.296.47-.006.302-.21.399-.617.746-1.542.393-.965.371-1.479.479-2.338.358-2.313.237-2.289.185-1.41.131-.508.449-.646.468-.506.804-.449-.073-.21-.341-.352-.317-.135-.293.081-.535.531-.693.359-.673-.056-.485.133-.445.484-.721.388-.481-.088-.869-.695-.438-.13-1.111.066-.325-.259-.284-.507-.226-.71-.169-.918.023-.959.4-1.746.153-.479 1.083-1.977.667-.933.664-.702.483-.414.456-.186.438-.438.805-1.418.831-1.225 1.034-2.301.5-.609 1.751-1.016.476-.016.404.253.383.529 1.075 2.288.084-.07-.188-.863-.392-2.609.063-1.085.615-1.168.252-.209.649.078 1.047.362.7.396.531.642.631.397.327-.02.233-.306.334-1.002.435-1.713.174-2.136-.086-2.576-.126-1.908-.168-1.214.092-1.019.527-1.231.483-.905 1.152-1.288.935-.344.554.087.729.606 1.011.371.913 1.165 1.479 2.645.981 1.312.813.586.801.993 1.184 2.084.62.886.368.32.325.051-.121-.588-.566-1.235-.866-1.371-1.921-2.493-1.059-1.784-.949-2.058-.698-1.237-1.266-1.236.017-.495 1.528-1.754 2.808-1.542 3.165-1.216 1.059.125 1.861-.511.175-.775.4-.349 1.733-1.088.497.015.763.517.813.981.376.883.511 1.505.25 2.096-.038 6.444.014 1.19.098.457.353-.681.421-1.271.379-.905.291-1.407.204-1.92.121-1.438-.495-1.64-.024-2.73.248-1.474h.693l2.867 5.035 1.128 1.067 1.284 2.617 1.5-.276 1.384.319.612-.095.302-.404-.43-1.083-1.966-3.014-.893-2.405-.625-3.051-.152-1.645.478-.298 2.196.035 3.3 1.429 4.22 4.848 2.077 1.573 3.722 5.382 1.123.798.453.167.342-.651.211-.71.016-.951-.18-1.196-.104-1.394-.026-1.597.252-3.21.6-1.061.265-1.208-.247-2.203-.703-1.526-2.737-3.997-.011-.483.553-.533.82-.313 6.783.969 1.172.354.5.347.219.457.281.195 1.457-.544-.035-.998-.182-.638-7.872-1.755-1.467-.604-.747-.046-.772.464-1.601.229-.739-.088-.958-2.115.867-2.582.73.059 1.387 1.011.822-1.414 1.304-1.178 1.29-.417 2.814-2.567.52-.226.656.138L357.099 9l.575.637.659 1.355.382.417.454.077.622.608.9-1.977.813-2.149.934-1.373 1.321.802.836 1.039.764 1.23 1.081.676 1.832 4.115.342.004.162-.344.173-.756.062-1.129.225-1.546-.163-.575-1.535-1.737-.29-.673-.294-1.115-.005-.927.285-.735.3-.337.992.306.328-.24.31-.626.373-1.181.294-.302.664-.035 1.021.76.894.064.322-.349.049-.742.078-.474.106-.2 3.24-.041.804-.178.628-.567.769-.067.672.339.832.722.827-.034 1.232-1.18L383.129 0l6.403.156L391.637.873M349.788 34.267l-.569.358-1.188-2.166-1.881-2.195-1.659-1.48-1.559-3.951-.123-1.427.221-1.262 1.361-.193 1.089-.583 2.772 2.509 1.386 2.095.47 1.693L350.035 31 349.788 34.267M423.317 39.028l-.289.635-.74-.254-.948-1.789-.632-1.483-.045-1.759.325-.788.506-.132.695 1.508.713 2.011L423.317 39.028M426.271 74.774l-1.188 1.811-1.757-.139-1.04-.834-.297-1.259.396-1.41 1.262-1.138 1.584-.715 1.436.43.198 1.423L426.271 74.774M422.384 101.829l-.372.474-.247-1.427-.223-1.922-.05-2.19.569-1.106.297-.247.198.247-.05.984v1.949l.198 1.328L422.384 101.829M425.313 106.232h-.545l-.202-.341.129-.605.759-1.966.253-.161.371.214.113 1.012-.248 1.005L425.313 106.232M274.566 110.337l-1 .113-.985-.499-.338-.387.015-.593.149-.206.532-.206.442-.046.298.092.701.366.507.365.333.114-.095.523L274.566 110.337M423.548 125.976l-.322.307-1.089-4.883v-1.803l.074-1.392.495-.108.421.751.198 2.867L423.548 125.976M425.181 133.202l.223 1.174.099 1.069.347.676.743-.096.297 1.25-.544.479-2.153-.191-.891.095-.619-.766.025-1.35.074-1.361.619-.782.52.685.619-.489L425.181 133.202M321.295 160.048l-.397.642-.323.367-.702 1.089-.121.038-.189-.141-.147-.286-.265-.069-.092-.181-.037-.147-.118-.094-.187-.059-.3.112-.275-.112-.208-.479.384-.322.237-.275.917-.108.259.126.163-.003.248-.075.542-.343.081-.16.485.201L321.295 160.048M325.454 175.874l-.263.057-.754-.439-.123-.166-.047-.203.029-.241.24-.45.451-.661.327-.124.203.415.199.556.026.281-.013.331-.052.28-.091.23L325.454 175.874M404.324 176.902l.099.505.001.238-.021.199-.055.143-.132.126.246.333.08.224.015.178-.157.344-1.118.454-.311.218-.388.539-.472.462-.157-.002-.183-.479-.746-.353-1.403.184-1.643.444-.583.207-.295-.11-.09-.166-.004-.231.194-.678.079-.173.377-.226.255-.6-.083-.655.098-.917.258-.143.645.327.417.069.739.042.993-.11.798-.374 1.456-1.07.258.014.185.38.136.186.433.291L404.324 176.902M330.674 177.469l-.375.023-.872-.155-.07-.1-.011-.189.116-.546.384-.073.457.299.493.425.068.2L330.674 177.469M327.71 185.082l.935.664.991.457.097.208.077.315.018.164-.022.152-.063.14.072.18.208.22.021.257-.248.44-.349.488-1.846.999-.653.169-1.614.682-.494-.028-.109-.032-.305-.3-.418-.279-.196-.217-.173-.312.069-.193.311-.076.442.005.649-.227-.18-.205-.17-.125-.118-.272-.271.053-.203-.156-.391-.099-1.021-.094-.666-.268-.196-.161-.173-.278-.15-.392.218-1.53.15-.392.346-.129.846.342.114-.147-.926-.568-.34-.339-.1-.268-.06-.395v-.232l.042-.234.083-.235.225-.318.938-.508 1.022.174 1.774.624.22.132.544.533L327.71 185.082M332.53 188.26l-.44.283-.089-.063-.089-.216-.227-.984-.067-.468.056-.584-.088-.413.397-.482.321-.083.433.126.733.49-.053.159-.159.255-.441.333-.156.748-.03.374.021.28L332.53 188.26M371.772 217.846l-.437.004-.145-.532.043-.582.492-.183.265.401-.095.596L371.772 217.846M345.853 247.406l-.322.694-.322-.151-.159-.31-.317-.144-.342.043-.005-.123 1.111-.742.53-.2-.038.313-.101.274L345.853 247.406" />
  </g>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option consist of not using CSS to scale your div but instead use the SVGElement's `transform` attribute :

```js
var zoomLevel = 1;

$('#controls').on('click', '.zoombutton', function(e) {
    var zoomDelta = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-delta'));
    zoomLevel += zoomDelta;
    $('#map>svg').attr('transform', 'translate('+zoomLevel*-200+',0) scale('+zoomLevel+')');
});

$('#controls').on('click', '.shadow', function(e) {
    $('#map').toggleClass('shadow');
});
```

```css
#controls {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#map.shadow g#world {
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25));
 filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25));
}
```

```html
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controls">
    <button type="button" class="zoombutton" data-delta="0.25">+</button>
    <button type="button" class="zoombutton" data-delta="-0.25">-</button>
    <button type="button" class="shadow">Toggle shadow</button>
</div>

<div id="map" class="shadow">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1009" height="665" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0  1009 665" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" currentScale="1">
  <g id="world" class="shadow">
   <path id="US" fill="#1976D2" d="M391.637.873l2.697 1.497 1.426 1.724.299-.057 1.933.657 1.835.817 3.051 2.11.428.687-.33.56-.758.384-3.899.682-7.073.833-4.047 1.605-1.287.082-.112 2.358.55.128.901-.315 3.17-2.365 1.186-.392 2.213.198 2.873.892 1.159-.313 2.067.233 2.417-.682 2.855-1.481.781 3.29 1.052 3.227.833-.354.713.18.241 1.046.39.441.808-.236 2.475.907 1.699 1.619.64.749.307 1.062.174.846-.267 1.035-1.062 1.828-1.343 1.661-1.812 1.267-2.088.789-16.045 2.611-.543.615-.322 1.559.214 2.004.75.311 1.752-1.123 3.031-1.072 2.227.051 5.324.915 1.571 2.369.831 3.574 1.842-.796.394-.611.29-1.065.231-1.151.173-1.236.193-.847.214-.451.459-.378 1.057-.457 2.772-.445.667.127.479 1.717.104.995.035 1.287-.015 1.574-.065 1.852-.236 1.812-.767 3.118-.617 1.673-.666 1.196-1.275 2.696-.442.713-1.402 3.075-.348 1.406-.021 1.021.241.194.407-.959.151-.688.262-.724 2.066-1.923.443-.54 1.352-2.326.863-.879.709-.927.376-.66 2.077-4.757 1.083-1.451 1.137-.003.201 2.449 1.363.375.592-.105.951.59.417.484.709.246.731.572.645-.615.188-.387.623-1.765.842-1.579.78-1.993.259-.487.41-.443.426-.175 1.16-.947.294-.066.626.3 2.766.156 1.509.488 2.101 1.347 1.464.733.678.646.987 1.377.796 1.429.37.417-.014.45-.275.619-1.972 2.146-.646 1.419-1.866 2.642-.912.898-.991.351-1.103.084-.716.374-.106.355.51 1.07.224.758-.032.671-.537.99-.203.223-1.938.73-.978 1.232-1.276.149-.902-.14-1.24 1.315.485 1.062.444.458 1.381.958.013.548-.66 1.101-.901 1.289-1.065.888-.4.132-.505-.223-.466.048-1.026.408-.977.065-1.745-.577-.944-.67-.497-.232-.626.064-.241.271-.987 1.593-.484 1.078-.311 1.096-.133 1.186.045 1.274.12.868.195.468.234.283.41.148.902-.14.354.08.108.254.195.802-.034.752-.164 1.052-.126 1.219-.09 1.382.048.75.365.164.171-.054.199.246.226.543.17.573.113.602-.059.495-.233.388-.525.437-1.293.859-.131.261-.102.52-.072.778-.156.705-.24.63-.218.375-.419.166-.549.022-.617.36-1.454 2.085-.022.23.544.663-.023.578-.671 2.459-.184 1.205-.146 1.638-.239 1.369-.333 1.106-.328 1.268-.322 1.424.05 1.085.423.751.559-.607.695-1.982.756-.864.816.271.711.396.908.779.76.484.656.635.271.533.272.749.002.471-.481.253-.159-.081-1.204-1.235-.586-.309-.778.372-.678.559.609 2.231.651 1.016 1.188.461.62.484.453.617.354.3.475-.132.639-.606.891-.033.402.301.291.56.131 1.042-.029 1.514-.097 1.131-.165.756-.321 1.008-.268.183-.377-.055-.351-.206-.325-.359-.492-.28-.989-.303-1-.66-.56-.163-1.185.084-1.278.418-.05.547-1.838 1.897-.377-.026-.51-.649-.714-.624-.418.004-.618.79-.154.305.008.287.455.677.185.155.235.13.817.162.355.177.334 2.076.53 1.27.227.258.2.093.65-.046.836-.427.292.342.616.417.36.104.438-.017.493.158.676 1.155-.266 1.444.423 1.147.676 1.175.16.428.065.772.015.507.051.463.086.416.089.814.093 1.206-.024.978-.143.754-.282.545-.42.338-.343-.089-.266-.516-.375-.552-.483-.588-.803-.069-1.182 1.732-.527.086-.429.171-.457.749-.673.449-.594-.178-1.043-.87.379.582.542.679.338.351.249.076.273-.081.394-.277.889-.771.235-.118.199.055.163.228.188.661.211 1.088-.027.921-.266.755-.228.483-.189.212v.167l.497.192.703-.979.223-1.226.322-1.425.569-.477.644.477.52 1.331.735 2.421.31.25.394.575.174.703-.046.829-.084.6-.122.372-.152.236-.274.15-.504.12-1.126-.251-.586-.006.073.808-1.186.692-1.337.271-1.266-.54-1.051-.833.345-1.171.197-1.31-.508-.873-.111-.019.175 1.347-.147.513-.574.623-.405.287-.036.167.199.145.129.278.061.411-.068.414-.198.417-.108.349-.018.282.181.342.381.401.413.198 1.935.086.775.215 1.838.941.082.288-.311 1.669-.17 1.588-.357.289-1.934.068-.623.246-.912.722-.876.862-.454.006-1.798-.752-.689-.504-1.48-1.434-1.114-2.206-.511.921-.313.438-.323.227-.311.035-.3-.157-.34-.347-.571-.808-.681-.803-.477-.383-.018.109.282.473.412.544 1.043 1.589.367.399-.037.283-.658.251-.8.54-.391.396-.604.958-.21.148-.904.24-.298-.058-.668-.526-1.007-.345-.593-.307-.824-.558.284.61 1.587.925.174.297-.325.552-.199.201-.378.042-.557-.115-.57.023-.583.162-.25.206.082.251.139.228.196.206.184-.002.444-.623.336-.044.889.154.899-.487.648-.211.486-.054 1.767-.749.367-.842.593-.339 1.318-.26 1.276.133.656.109.531.798.712.563.594.64.696.21.403.847 1.128.941.718.202.443.446.036 1.877.047.804-.191 2.206-.577.504.115 1.148-.151.922-.573-.349-.587-.607-1.407-.946-1.309-.611-.509-.556-.599-.432-.813-1.768-.529-2.225-.232-1.111-.445-.062-.572.298-.5.315-.239.537-1.698.736-.617.502-.352-.015-1.268.754.508.36.237.045.513-.203.308-.26 1.156-.714.928-.123.337-.309.709-.442.481-.117.067.112.052.202.339 2.703-.142.712-.382.308-.817.503-.212.244.241.426.768-.401.498-.437.266.159.435.667.491.341 1.248 1.018.591.558.832.537.94.742.245.261.859.383.184.131.355 1.296.296.144.855.082-.15.5-.835 1.105-.432.352-.107.216.041.386.025.645.174 1.18.196-1.092.137-.518.183-.155.18-.023.584-.492.587.264.152 1.239.075 1.148-.051.986.064 1.521-.022.511.139.441.144 1.816.144.542-.289.484-.893.21-.353-.238-.883.08-.0001-.426-.043-.49-.003-.343-.059-.311-.042-1.798-.25.446-.015.365-.066.371-.153 1.927-.228.47-.707-.113-.696.069-.385-.071-1.302-.875-.504-.796-.446-1.203-.275-1.131-.104-1.059-.313-.866-.52-.671-.614-.545-.708-.419-.622-.542-.536-.666-.589-.52-.644-.372-.916-.16-1.339.059-.904-.42-.215.036-.211.217.155.617 1.038.282.8.064 1.061-.04.649.158.238.355.164.63.09.902-.21.712-.763.787-.402.368-1.175.704-.398.156-.98.048-.753-.067-.991-.35-.562-.071-1.163-.047L396 176.287l.3.375.493.212.347.252.036.477-.125.705-.129.491-.213.368-.763.694-.316.219-1.422.723-.099.139.333-.019.899-.256.259.007 1.476.625 1.176-.037 2.382-.577.196.011.156.091.158.216.16.342-.192.331-.544.318-.847.313-.367.211-.351.32-.653.767-.191.792.687.3.309-.38.364-.847.328-.499.773-.339.944.172.729-.201 1.49-.843.267-.052 2.192.483 1.987.945 1.048.346 1.387.204 2.494-.093.219.148-.081.333-.145.281-.416.391-.505.258-.312.073-.266.184-.597.18-.153.146.207.636-.098.098-.526.011-.886.413-.727-.029-.152.06.138.153.146.295.155.436-.085.311-.326.185-.247.06-.853-.259-.138.039.125.187.071.284.017.382-.209.319-.436.257-.813.706-.354.201-.746.166-.157.092.303.538-.034.215-.504.579-.763.36-.104.194-.07.52-.056.207-.202.297-.724.564-.513.28-.254.229-.315.382-.397.202-.479.023-.454.143-.746.405-.52.134-1.642.696-.772.111-.668.248-1.375.661-.655.212-.454.251-.496.072-.807-.163-.435-.006-.268.099-.245.202-.405.552-.344.042-1.128-.437.023.198.298.473-.014.334-.671.339-.361.086-.533-.139-.705-.366-.905-.766-1.109-1.175-.534-.399.039.379.124.37.209.359.042.26-.124.161-.163.081-.203.0001-.035.091.331.558.261.571-.024.54-.31.51-.266.298-.222.088-1.317 1.262-.367.159-.167.155-.137.232-.383 1.035-.155.315-.308.409-.129.071-.037.167.056.262-.085.436-.225.608-.767 1.668-.618 1.542-.271.502-.198.212-.125-.076-.307.039-.149.269-.135.485-.147.369-.159.253-1.24 1.088-.319.201-.287-.127-.339.049-.703-.573-.122-.211-.454-.473.015.247.076.136.063.199.159.244.352 1.277-.278.261-.249.297-.635.501-.687.836-.253.233-.057-.681.029-.204-.388-.331.012.238-.04.222-.281.882-.078.152-.139-.034-.302.162-.309-.077-.263-.4-.104-.208-.478.571-.232-.015-.039.478-.225.435-.297.188-.415-.015-.254.257-.563-.275-.13-.517.446-.711.126-.294-.082-.363.108-.47.852-1.499.577-.764-.033-.137-.784-.167-.685-.263-.667-.09-.295.089.47.44.665.426-.327.406-.282.43-.292 1.165-.187.475-.725-.545-.343-.185.218.605.635.572.041.188-.004.677-1.216.595-1.269.09-.911.168-1.537.204h-.597l-.051.228 1.503 1.036.219.189-.209.355-.311.22-.488.757-.255.26-.632.357-1.163-.398-.598.178-.572-.125-.012.435.171.317.173.785.384-.061.488-.247.377.593.248 1 .433.505.192.39.078.367-.27.365-.559.514-.62.096.034.406-.268.291-.569-.085-.266-.204-.276-.096-1.132-.109 1.14.78.405.362.18-.214.395-.052.583.198-.097 1.306.255 1.051.031.235-.621.626-.001.583-.37.162-.398-.037-.021.637-.27.396.048.248.077.221-.246.402-.222.488-.318.426-.168-.044-.505.028-.607-.036-.492-.554-.204-.185-.23-.121.088.357.138.214.454.4.836.493-.026.349-.223.151-.521.945-.185.021-.234.243-.722-.082-.303-.097-.891.062-.303-.083-.26.04.242.266.51.239.58.24.882.181-.032.342-.221.28.127.417-.099.298-.042.354-.206.82.24.56.261.273-.03.359.123.572-.392.509-.325-.019-.463.114-.154.224.734.211-.067.379-.2.474-.21 1.021-.427 1.738-.2 1.71-.917 1.394-.325.039-.082.055-.447-.071-.702-.321-.543-.106-.367-.004-.047.16.304.258.465.108.372.171.667.159.232.308.159.328-.023.18-.0001.212.119 1.139-.314.392-.24.354-.833-.049-.145-.124-.804-.373.049.175.582.506.203.252-.136.052-.235.019-.327.17-.591-.092.033-.255.112-.263-.27.045-.301.133-.175-.049-.146.015-.083-.132-.114-.515.136-.259.487-.672.155-.362-.135-.165-.348.388-.359.615-.16.371-.225.072-.559-.187-1.591-.861.047-.525-.015-.436.464-.055.337-.19.302-.233.34-.425.312-.704-.04-.054-.915.898-.563.299-.272.055-.136-.132-.453-.288-.294-.131-.671-.214-.119-.115-.197-.092-.268-.92.346-1.124.238-.328.151-.38.085-.505-.059-.216-.202.074-.094.173.015.271-.116.188-.8.431-.802.349-.38.33-.247.257-.193.252-.295-.022-.407.051-.279.164-.408-.101-.266-.243-.321-.028-.36.117-.249-.001.021.165.166.405-.275.027-.522.016-.263-.118-.206-.154-.171-.215.103-.282.84-.518.381-.301-.249-.103-.806.093-.134-.078-.54.047.023-.775-.131-.193-.009-.091-.187-.217-.177-.054-.11-.078-.912-.175-.119-.435-.063-.449-.174-.559-.437-.146-.236-.243.188-.249.082-.316-.202-.145-.129-.223.019-.145-.164-.393-.049-.307.188-.289.516-.327.167-.132.086-.143.592-.241-.504-.17-.315-.026-.23.08-.212.32-.198.212-.772.069-.114-.11-.054-.452.044-.349.321-.492-.37-.244-.339-.08-.385-.229-.356-.242-.306-.282-.298-.333-.095-.042.107-.349.061-.288.009-.62-.12-.258.267-.532.359-.583.794-.869-.84.419-.69.911-.146.042-.051-.165-.262-.591-.197-.162-.088-.178-.393-.317-.17-.244-.242-.472-.344-.564-.489-1.117-.79-1.295-.195-.732.245-.933-.271-.646.75-.3 1.073-.337.557-.281.321-.084.682-.052.228-.283-.379.072-.255-.037-.016-.132.094-.235.061-.304-.13.055-.667.523-.986.414-.77.23-.125-.012-.27.139-.155.04-.12-.04-.272-.396-.073-.259.489-.705.365-.966.483-.635.341-.08.571.034.201.056-.064-.377.024-.183.463-.22.54-.098.384.069.242.444.311.816.419.275-.019-.391-.217-.505-.081-.778-.276-.329-.221-.162-.612.079-.368-.572-.083-.21-.009-.28-.368-.824-.118-.414-.195-.552-.104-.03.132.695.172.487.246 1.066.122.428-.165.338-.311.334-.275.199-.65.238.14-.52.089-.512-.327.182-.304.372-.105.514-.195.465-.579 1.137-.228.628-.216.309-.246.085-.213-.245-.181-.577-.085-.453-.001-1.18.023-.553-.099-.748-.313-1.753-.066-.629-.529-.335-.008-.108-.138-.36-.107-.361.088-.132.126-.095.791-.534.586-.6.701-.945.286-.294 1.028-.227.456-.031-.004-.169-.153-.067-.694.044-.925.38-.159.137-.405.589-.312.321-.878.731h-.57l-.588-.876-.657.168-.443-.058-.129-.132-.098-1.204.357-1.415-.386-.014-.08-.057-.204-.324-.133-.097.099-.172.951-.676 1.423-1.334.612-.527.378-.228.286-.261.348-.568.115-.249.194-.201.409-.227.447-.344.725-.776.095-.288-.158-.067-.339.266-.689.71-.492.398-1.679 1.771-.715.64-.389.408-.302.388-.319.276-.338.165-.72.123-.354.143-.213-.104-.094-.828.072-.492-.034-.487.18-.7.267-.497.112-.271.047-.186.55-.517.303-.229.214-.52 1.221-.185.315.019.167-.07.125-.151-.121-.117-.366-.083-.973.016-.899-.089-.41-.09-.198.052-.327-.152-.357-.291-.554-1.072.222-1.386.019-.666.704-.585.376-.194.534-.442.713-.754.851-.462.434-.086.36.066 1.332.655.685.128.602-.157.755.229 1.336.938.258-.139-.075-.227-1.49-.993.008-.298.381-.078.407-.29-.229-.172-.99.149-.286.238-.96.123-.501-.202-.45-.101-.675-.432-.565.141-.357.17-.631.161-.228.115-1.233 1.352-.519.28-.369-.092.259-.878.075-.348v-.379l.107-.521.632-.997.397-1.098.168-.685.311-.077.424.101 1.274.444 1.06.528.782.141.514.015.22-.168.174-.293.067-.203.05-.416.059-.148.172-.182.351-.635.107-.453-.115-.265-.234.027-.457.174-.062.072.008.142-.441.701-.481.161-1.107.234-.505.017-.898-.325-.136-.127-.093-.239-1.102.054-.329.072-.262-.031.128-.416.348-.463.488-1.515.409-.39.812-.364.847.059 1.465 1.177.442.102.405-.095.969-.393.178-.16.349-.489.407-.84-.02-.199-.625.47-.333.126h-.282l.262-1.542.102-1.19.098-.297.821.089 1.122-.162.267-.262-.004-.116-.45-.159-.217-.335-.377.106-.505.223-.634-.025.053-.517.465-1.089.048-.499.181-1.001.019-.516.235-.503.733-.359.308-.215.017-.236-.439-.901.111-.25.345-.228.128-.167-.088-.104-.317-.1-.488.2-.54.096-.478-.301-.374-.145-.236.045-.643.515-.225.017-.278-.143-1.842-.446-.229-.158-.66-.775-.544-.514-.724-.563-.939-.429-1.153-.294-.69-.277-.34-.392-.583-.865-.443-.724-.083-.359.26-.445.265-.32.499-.263.861.087.462.117.509.251.385.047.799-.071.813.16.481.176.632.366 1.744 1.549.728.535.316.064 1.305.57.209-.011.534-.267.053-.173-.18-.171-.576-.133-.676-.632-.419-.503-.048-.835.055-.47.105-.214.074-.723-.392-.431-.273-.136-.727-.631-.061-.157.349-.074.342.043.733.32.384.044.28-.125.032-.129-.446-.364-.558-.653-1.166-.097-.756.074-.483-.225-.514-.366-.331-.094-.675.23-.341.029-.311-.081-.307-1.16.082-.349.241-.151.182-.377.127-.395.4-.387 2.195-.865.554-.646-.024-.1-.374.12-.478.292-.319.06-1.292-.377-.202.086-.523.541-.71.585-.327-.036-.438-.346-.069-.247-.032-.297.481-.408.154-.216.311-.583-.016-.289-.531.159-.069-.269.008-.461-.051-.585-.13-.58-.436-.895-.181-.23-.149-.333-.329-1.221.095-.307.292-.233.056-.107-.697.193-.076.212.131.313.094.416.056.518.097.452.252.494.202.259.329.684.144.749-.042.393-.255.399-.412.429-.125.355-.056.353-.321.326-.197-.122-.156-.019.184.58.119.592-.143.591-.381.357-.207.011-.407.289-1.042.151-.363-.071-.665-.293-.789-.16-.313-.396-.41-.723-.207-.65-.004-.577.111-.421.226-.266.272-1.707.384-1.391.967-1.446.276-.526.091-.283-.0001-.216-.156-.137-1.189 1.795-.733.19-.219-.402.066-.716.131-.167.593.068.23-.4-.371-.606-.395-.16-.092-.153.406-.464.94.034.212-.325.34-.351.378-.654.141-.552.032-.475-.082-.384-.008-.386.064-.388-.099-.43-.261-.472-.581-.462-.171.522-.181.214-.254.048-.234-.22-.245-.079-.24-.196-.25-.063-.097-.158-.063-.444-.005-.566.282-.266.393-.209.263-.397.173-.577.025-.633-.123-.688-.319-.621-.591.604-.232.148-.053-.432-.082-.32-.248-.436-.327-.318-.314-.212-.014-.323.074-.365.14-.426.181-.893.199.08.166-.082-.096-.741-.16-.625-.188-.357-.007-.155-.043-.182-.145-.441-.163-.324-.284-.921-.205-.353-.263-.183-.283-.001-.455.244-.839.28-.665.133-.111-.073.333-.351.49-.366.648-.249.189-.612-.07-.531.027-.505-.178-.533.173-.296.59-.299.268-.046.266-.381-.748-.923-.784-.607-.196-.248-.172-.408-.148-.57-.242-.572-.334-.576-.488-.557-1.258-1.024-.432-.71-.398-1.092-.199-.468-.207-.347-.876-.816-.106-.362.905-.968.088-.388-.37-1.185-.378-.872-.412-.311-.613-.16-.562-.39-.511-.62-.51-.455-.764-.434-1.278-1.121-1.97-1.208-.88-.71-.524-.259-.69-.066-1.335-.667-1.122-.214-.692.098-.226-.111-.512-.681-.801-.392-.414.149-.514.73-.62.717-.33.097-.49-.655-.247-.459-.236-.157-.225.148-.438.603-.417.434-.617.514-.493.246-.633.06-.159.186-.244.008-.328-.168-.308-.334-.287-.501-.253-.271-.22-.04-.505.26-.639.762-.292.183-.245-.079-.3-.237-.601-.608-.333.059-.242.213.067.504.563 1.19.503.843-.425.099-3.712-1.141-.473-.276-.683-.695-.568-.428-.967-1.111-.745-.604-.247-.474-.065-.327.237-.443 1.5-1.503.573-.305 1.166-.365.275-.229.092-.182-.306-.329-1.527.118-1.36-.22-1.184-.607-.206-.202-.201-.373-.195-.544.044-.611.284-.679.167-.468.049-.254-1.488 1.672-.608.582-.482-.178-.338-.275-.166-.307.006-.339.055-.248.103-.155-.787-.694-.354-.547-.038-.566.279-.586.273-.426.267-.267.728-.232 2.658-.445 1.903.427.648-1.419.438-.455 1.28-.475 1.97-.066 1.391.263.652.335.888.737.051-.222-.214-.666-.015-.555.359-.969.165-.611-.112-.639-.39-.667-.69-.86-.372-.071-.413.208-.496.477-1.031 1.196-.487.249-.812.063-.449-.15-.434-.179-.678-.633-.247-.119-.3.278-.352.673-.339.47-.327.268-.305.116-.426-.055-1.755-1.044-.396-.467-.023-.71-.539-.691-.609-.121-.074-.232.772-1.073.576-.44-.092-.133-.836-.023-.564.573-.323.097-.743.016-.78-.287-.332-.251-.344-.578-.386-.326-1.165-.496-.263-.271-.249-.451-.952-1.283-.576-.949-.075-.541.665-1.167.029-.271-.285-.507-.119-.375.098-.519.582-1.155.216-.314 1.043-.683 1.045-.998.38-.225.339-.052 1.373.06.425-.247.361-.49.593-.498 1.237-.759 2.75-1.154.179-.137.016-.22-.247-.599-.052-.29.563-.54 1.271-.855.869-.413.559-.03.451-.185.633-.542.358-.096 2.163-.213.957.296.47-.006.302-.21.399-.617.746-1.542.393-.965.371-1.479.479-2.338.358-2.313.237-2.289.185-1.41.131-.508.449-.646.468-.506.804-.449-.073-.21-.341-.352-.317-.135-.293.081-.535.531-.693.359-.673-.056-.485.133-.445.484-.721.388-.481-.088-.869-.695-.438-.13-1.111.066-.325-.259-.284-.507-.226-.71-.169-.918.023-.959.4-1.746.153-.479 1.083-1.977.667-.933.664-.702.483-.414.456-.186.438-.438.805-1.418.831-1.225 1.034-2.301.5-.609 1.751-1.016.476-.016.404.253.383.529 1.075 2.288.084-.07-.188-.863-.392-2.609.063-1.085.615-1.168.252-.209.649.078 1.047.362.7.396.531.642.631.397.327-.02.233-.306.334-1.002.435-1.713.174-2.136-.086-2.576-.126-1.908-.168-1.214.092-1.019.527-1.231.483-.905 1.152-1.288.935-.344.554.087.729.606 1.011.371.913 1.165 1.479 2.645.981 1.312.813.586.801.993 1.184 2.084.62.886.368.32.325.051-.121-.588-.566-1.235-.866-1.371-1.921-2.493-1.059-1.784-.949-2.058-.698-1.237-1.266-1.236.017-.495 1.528-1.754 2.808-1.542 3.165-1.216 1.059.125 1.861-.511.175-.775.4-.349 1.733-1.088.497.015.763.517.813.981.376.883.511 1.505.25 2.096-.038 6.444.014 1.19.098.457.353-.681.421-1.271.379-.905.291-1.407.204-1.92.121-1.438-.495-1.64-.024-2.73.248-1.474h.693l2.867 5.035 1.128 1.067 1.284 2.617 1.5-.276 1.384.319.612-.095.302-.404-.43-1.083-1.966-3.014-.893-2.405-.625-3.051-.152-1.645.478-.298 2.196.035 3.3 1.429 4.22 4.848 2.077 1.573 3.722 5.382 1.123.798.453.167.342-.651.211-.71.016-.951-.18-1.196-.104-1.394-.026-1.597.252-3.21.6-1.061.265-1.208-.247-2.203-.703-1.526-2.737-3.997-.011-.483.553-.533.82-.313 6.783.969 1.172.354.5.347.219.457.281.195 1.457-.544-.035-.998-.182-.638-7.872-1.755-1.467-.604-.747-.046-.772.464-1.601.229-.739-.088-.958-2.115.867-2.582.73.059 1.387 1.011.822-1.414 1.304-1.178 1.29-.417 2.814-2.567.52-.226.656.138L357.099 9l.575.637.659 1.355.382.417.454.077.622.608.9-1.977.813-2.149.934-1.373 1.321.802.836 1.039.764 1.23 1.081.676 1.832 4.115.342.004.162-.344.173-.756.062-1.129.225-1.546-.163-.575-1.535-1.737-.29-.673-.294-1.115-.005-.927.285-.735.3-.337.992.306.328-.24.31-.626.373-1.181.294-.302.664-.035 1.021.76.894.064.322-.349.049-.742.078-.474.106-.2 3.24-.041.804-.178.628-.567.769-.067.672.339.832.722.827-.034 1.232-1.18L383.129 0l6.403.156L391.637.873M349.788 34.267l-.569.358-1.188-2.166-1.881-2.195-1.659-1.48-1.559-3.951-.123-1.427.221-1.262 1.361-.193 1.089-.583 2.772 2.509 1.386 2.095.47 1.693L350.035 31 349.788 34.267M423.317 39.028l-.289.635-.74-.254-.948-1.789-.632-1.483-.045-1.759.325-.788.506-.132.695 1.508.713 2.011L423.317 39.028M426.271 74.774l-1.188 1.811-1.757-.139-1.04-.834-.297-1.259.396-1.41 1.262-1.138 1.584-.715 1.436.43.198 1.423L426.271 74.774M422.384 101.829l-.372.474-.247-1.427-.223-1.922-.05-2.19.569-1.106.297-.247.198.247-.05.984v1.949l.198 1.328L422.384 101.829M425.313 106.232h-.545l-.202-.341.129-.605.759-1.966.253-.161.371.214.113 1.012-.248 1.005L425.313 106.232M274.566 110.337l-1 .113-.985-.499-.338-.387.015-.593.149-.206.532-.206.442-.046.298.092.701.366.507.365.333.114-.095.523L274.566 110.337M423.548 125.976l-.322.307-1.089-4.883v-1.803l.074-1.392.495-.108.421.751.198 2.867L423.548 125.976M425.181 133.202l.223 1.174.099 1.069.347.676.743-.096.297 1.25-.544.479-2.153-.191-.891.095-.619-.766.025-1.35.074-1.361.619-.782.52.685.619-.489L425.181 133.202M321.295 160.048l-.397.642-.323.367-.702 1.089-.121.038-.189-.141-.147-.286-.265-.069-.092-.181-.037-.147-.118-.094-.187-.059-.3.112-.275-.112-.208-.479.384-.322.237-.275.917-.108.259.126.163-.003.248-.075.542-.343.081-.16.485.201L321.295 160.048M325.454 175.874l-.263.057-.754-.439-.123-.166-.047-.203.029-.241.24-.45.451-.661.327-.124.203.415.199.556.026.281-.013.331-.052.28-.091.23L325.454 175.874M404.324 176.902l.099.505.001.238-.021.199-.055.143-.132.126.246.333.08.224.015.178-.157.344-1.118.454-.311.218-.388.539-.472.462-.157-.002-.183-.479-.746-.353-1.403.184-1.643.444-.583.207-.295-.11-.09-.166-.004-.231.194-.678.079-.173.377-.226.255-.6-.083-.655.098-.917.258-.143.645.327.417.069.739.042.993-.11.798-.374 1.456-1.07.258.014.185.38.136.186.433.291L404.324 176.902M330.674 177.469l-.375.023-.872-.155-.07-.1-.011-.189.116-.546.384-.073.457.299.493.425.068.2L330.674 177.469M327.71 185.082l.935.664.991.457.097.208.077.315.018.164-.022.152-.063.14.072.18.208.22.021.257-.248.44-.349.488-1.846.999-.653.169-1.614.682-.494-.028-.109-.032-.305-.3-.418-.279-.196-.217-.173-.312.069-.193.311-.076.442.005.649-.227-.18-.205-.17-.125-.118-.272-.271.053-.203-.156-.391-.099-1.021-.094-.666-.268-.196-.161-.173-.278-.15-.392.218-1.53.15-.392.346-.129.846.342.114-.147-.926-.568-.34-.339-.1-.268-.06-.395v-.232l.042-.234.083-.235.225-.318.938-.508 1.022.174 1.774.624.22.132.544.533L327.71 185.082M332.53 188.26l-.44.283-.089-.063-.089-.216-.227-.984-.067-.468.056-.584-.088-.413.397-.482.321-.083.433.126.733.49-.053.159-.159.255-.441.333-.156.748-.03.374.021.28L332.53 188.26M371.772 217.846l-.437.004-.145-.532.043-.582.492-.183.265.401-.095.596L371.772 217.846M345.853 247.406l-.322.694-.322-.151-.159-.31-.317-.144-.342.043-.005-.123 1.111-.742.53-.2-.038.313-.101.274L345.853 247.406" />
  </g>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, this totally *does* scale the SVG without distorting, so thanks for this.  Unfortunately, as there are markers & other bits displayed on top of the map in regular HTML markup, and they don't get transformed in the same way (that's why I was scaling the container). Sorry, probably should have added that to the demo for clarity.