# Adding drop shadows to SVG symbols

Tags: html, css, svg, shadow

I'm building a website that is very heavy on icons, so I'm working with SVG symbols to reduce duplication. In some cases the design calls for the symbols to have a drop shadow, and not in others. I'm struggling to figure out how I can add a drop shadow.

Example of my SVG:

```
<svg id="icons-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
...
<symbol id="icon-communications" viewBox="1400 0 200 200">
    <title>Communications</title>
    <rect style="fill: currentColor" x="1447.3" y="95.3" width="105.3" height="5.3"/>
    <rect style="fill: currentColor" x="1447.3" y="78" width="105.3" height="5.3"/>
    <polygon style="fill: currentColor" points="1463.2,127.9 1468,130.1 1475.7,113.6 1470.9,111.4   "/>
    ...
</symbol>
...
</svg>
```

I then include the icon on page using the standard:

```
<svg class="icon-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-communications"/>
</svg>
```

I can then set the color of the icon like this:

```
.icon-svg use {
    color: blue;
}
.error .icon-svg use {
    color: red;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to add a drop shadow. I've tried CSS box-shadow, and also filter: drop-shadow(), but neither seem to do anything. e.g.

```
.someClass .icon-svg use {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 0 0 20px #000 );
    filter: drop-shadow( 0 0 20px #000 );
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah...I don't *think* you can do that with a `<use>` only an inline SVG. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3?rq=1

Comment: Alternatively would it be possible to include it with the SVG and the switch it off using CSS, or would that have exactly the same limitation?

Comment: I think it would have the same issues. I'm just assuming from my reading here. Reaching *into* a `<use>` and applying CSS to (effectively) *parts' is difficult if not impossible. I'd wait for some SVG experts to come along. If @RobertLongson comments..take it as gospel.

Comment: My experience has been the SVG renders OK, without objectionable time delays, with as many as 5000 separate clones rather than <use> of an element. It allows much more access for dynamic customization of an element.

Comment: I have a solution, but doesn't work in IE. If I modify the style attribute on the original symbol SVG to include 'filter:var(--filter-name)' I can then set the filter name referencing an SVG filter in my CSS e.g. '--filter-name: url(#dropshadow);'.

Answer (score 0):

Use an SVG Filter:

```css
.icon-svg use {
    color: blue;
}
.error .icon-svg use {
    color: red;
}

.icon-svg {
  -webkit-filter: url(#dropshadowy);
}
```

```html
<svg id="icons-svg" >
  <defs>
<filter id="dropshadowy">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4"/>
  <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode/>
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </feMerge>
</filter>
    
<symbol id="icon-communications" viewBox="1400 0 200 200">
    <title>Communications</title>

    <rect style="fill: currentColor" x="1447.3" y="95.3" width="105.3" height="5.3"/>
    <rect style="fill: currentColor" x="1447.3" y="78" width="105.3" height="5.3"/>
    <polygon style="fill: currentColor" points="1463.2,127.9 1468,130.1 1475.7,113.6 1470.9,111.4   "/>

</symbol>
  </defs>

</svg>


<svg class="icon-svg" >
 
    <use xlink:href="#icon-communications"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in FF 47.0.1 or Edge 14.14393.  Yes in Chrome.

I can't figure out why your original code doesn't work - I did the same thing on my web site [http://potoococha.net/][1] and it works in all browsers.  I would suggest closing all your tags, use, rect and polygon may not be "self-closing".  And you shouldn't need to use the use element name in your css - just the class names are enough.


  [1]: http://potoococha.net/

Comment: Yes I didn't write the cross browser polyfills