# Pulse animation with box-shadow on a polygon

Tags: html, css, animation, box-shadow

I try to use a animation on a polygon so i create a css for drop-shadow.
So i set up animation over CSS.

```css
    .imp-shape-poly {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
      animation: pulse 2s infinite;
    }
    
    .imp-shape-poly:hover {
      animation: none;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
      0% {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
      }
      70% {
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
      }
      100% {
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
      }
    }
    @keyframes pulse {
      0% {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
      }
      70% {
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
      }
      100% {
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
      }
    }
```

```html
<svg class="hs-poly-svg" viewBox="0 0 2200 950" preserveAspectRatio="none"><polygon class="imp-shape imp-shape-poly" style="fill: rgba(84, 175, 223, 0.4);stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);stroke-width: 0px;stroke-dasharray: 0;stroke-linecap: round;" data-index="0" id="poly-3942" data-shape-title="tag" points="590.634,345.6535689655172 686.0944444444444,379.3739827586206 805.4200000000001,380.77899999999994 690.4335555555556,340.03349999999995 "></polygon><polygon class="imp-shape imp-shape-poly" style="fill: rgba(84, 175, 223, 0.4);stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);stroke-width: 0px;stroke-dasharray: 0;stroke-linecap: round;" data-index="1" id="poly-9033" data-shape-title="liest" points="551.606,438.7057777777778 580.6370810810811,435.48 647.9120631205234,464.64292129912565 668.0686486486486,481.91705555555563 670.956,799.992888888889 651.601945945946,812.896 564.5087027027026,722.5742222222221 "></polygon><polygon class="imp-shape imp-shape-poly" style="fill: rgba(84, 175, 223, 0.4);stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);stroke-width: 0px;stroke-dasharray: 0;stroke-linecap: round;" data-index="2" id="poly-2644" data-shape-title="poly-2644" points="1007.6357892063631,512.9048582089553 1005.5980000000001,612.3795 1279.3647089173871,597.1110149253732 1281.632,497.2015 "></polygon><polygon class="imp-shape imp-shape-poly" style="fill: rgba(84, 175, 223, 0.4);stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);stroke-width: 0px;stroke-dasharray: 0;stroke-linecap: round;" data-index="3" id="poly-7367" data-shape-title="poly-7367" points="1344.4066308252995,653.2295 1488.718,637.1006111111112 1472.5889807756023,593.9780000000001 1321.914,606.0271236844445 "></polygon></svg>
```

You can steck out here my demo.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BboWpW

Comment: Do check - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13624469/7867822

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey. I want a pulse effect and try to use a box-shadow for it. So it looks like the shadow pulse behind the shapes.

Comment: You may not be able to apply `box-shadow` to `<polygon>` elements. Check the link to another answer given above.