# How to apply box-shadow effect on svg circle by changing svg filter element in D3 chart

Tags: css, d3.js, svg, box-shadow

I'm trying to make the svg circle with box-shadow on "D3 chart" like this css code:

```css
 box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.1);
 background-color: #ffffff;
```

I put this code in svg filter element, but the result was not what I thought to make. Anyone knows how to put?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG drop shadow using css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - so this risks being closed without an answer. Please provide a copy of the SVG filter code that you wrote and what you expected the result to be as an image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use svg circle like this:

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.1)" stroke-width="6" fill="#ffffff" stroke-opacity="0.1"/>
</svg>
```

Or:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 200)
.attr("height", 200);

var circle = svg.append("circle")
.attr("cx", 100)
.attr("cy", 100).
.attr("r", 50)
.style("fill", "#ffffff")
.style("stroke", "rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.1)")
.style("stroke-width", 6);
```

This worked for me.
Hope it helps you too :)