# SVG Applying filter with shadow to <path> hides the line if it's vertical or horizontal

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to draw some line graphs with shadows (using d3.js but this does not matter I hope) using the recipe from here [SVG drop shadow using css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3)

I faced some strange problem, if it is a vertical or horizontal line applying the filter is hiding the line completely. [image] Actually here are 3 lines (`<path>`) with the same styles and attributes (except `d`). If i disable the filter for these 2 line they are become visible.
[image]
What I'm doing wrong? I created jsfiddle with simplified version of svg https://jsfiddle.net/ap7t93rh/1/

Comment: Well, the question is actually a duplicate, but I have to say that it's hard to find the original one if not searching exactly for "vertical" and  "feDropShadow"... At least I could not... Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be applying the filter to the group of lines: `<g transform="translate(90 40)" style="filter: url('#dropshadow');">` instead of applying it to each line.

Also: I would apply this `stroke="#400040" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2px"` to the group as well

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 900 634">
        <rect fill="#ffffff" width="1875" height="634"></rect>
        <defs>
            <filter id="dropshadow">
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"></feGaussianBlur>
                <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"></feOffset>
                <feComponentTransfer>
                    <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.5"></feFuncA>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feMerge>
                    <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
                    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
                </feMerge>
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <g transform="translate(90 40)" stroke="#400040" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2px" style="filter: url('#dropshadow');">


            <!-- diagonal -->
            <path class="graph graph-line graph3 graph-7" d="M5,0L1731,554" ></path>

            <!-- vertical -->
            <path class="graph graph-line graph3 graph-7"  d="M500,0L500,554" ></path>

            <!-- horizontal -->
            <path class="graph graph-line graph3 graph-7"  d="M5,354L1731,354" ></path>
                
                
      
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: That works only when all 3 lines in one group, if you remove diagonal and vertical lines for example (so it will be group with one `<path` - horizontal) line will disappear again. Actually in real graph I'm applying shadow filter to the group that contains the line, optional dots and optional values. If dots and values off - line become invisible.

Comment: The only thing I'm thinking of for now is to put some transparent object inside the group where the horizontal line is...

Comment: @Dimanoid I tried this, adding such object inside group, and applying filter on whole group. Still didn't help. Seems like even when you apply filter on a group, filter is computed for each individual svg element (path in my case).