# how to get rid of the border for icons?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, web-frontend

My goal is to make the icon glow, but if apply shadow it comes with a ugly rounded div.

**React code :**

```
<SunIcon
  className="h-10 w-10 rounded-3xl mr-2.5 text-suncolor shadow-sunshadow"
     />
```

The sunshadow is `0 0 20px 7px rgb(255 204 51 / 66%)`

**Output i get:** I get that outline

[image]

*I also tried using outline none, but doesn't work*

Comment: Which icon library are you using?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking a guess that the icon library you're using is rendering SVG elements. Using `box-shadow` on an SVG results in the effect in the image you posted.

SVG can display shadows, which you can read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6094674/795705), but when using a preexisting library, modifying them can be difficult.

For a CSS-driven shadow, you *could* use `drop-shadow` in a `filter`, however I have always found the effect to be too faded:

```
filter: drop-shadow( 0 0 5px rgba(255, 204, 51, .66));
```

Be aware that `drop-shadow` has [limited browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow()#browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

Elements are always Squares and rectangles (or with a radius, even a circle) but never custom shapes

Try it with a `::before` pseudo element

```css
.iconClassName::before, .iconClassName::before:hover, .iconClassName::before:active { content:"";  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 7px rgb(255 204 51 / 66%)}
```

Maybe you have to edit width/height, position...

Try to remove your Border-Radius, but without minimal example code it is hard to try