# How to apply shadow color to hero-icons with tailwind css?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind v3 and hero icons in a react project.

```
import { PlusCircleIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid';
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

interface HeaderProps {
  title: string;
}

export const Header: FunctionComponent<HeaderProps> = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <nav className="flex justify-between items-center">
      <h1 className="text-white text-7xl font-bold pt-2">{title}</h1>
      <PlusCircleIcon className="h-14 w-14 text-accent  shadow-sm shadow-white" />
    </nav>
  );
};
```

[image: button]

How do I apply shadow color around the circle?

Comment: Can you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG drop shadow using css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `drop-shadow` property like that:

```
<PlusCircleIcon className="h-14 w-14 drop-shadow-lg" />
```

you can use another shadow size (e.g. md, lg, xl, 2xl). the problem with with class is that you can't change the color so that, you need to use a custom class name like this:

```
<PlusCircleIcon className="h-14 w-14 drop-shadow-[0_5px_5px_rgba(255,0,0,1)]" />
```

this way you can change the color and the size of the shadow without having to write custom CSS.